# Checking if a variable is defined?

Tags: ruby, reflection

How can I check whether a variable is defined in Ruby?  Is there an `isset`-type method available?

Answer (score 818, accepted):

Use the `defined?` keyword ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F)). It will return a String with the kind of the item, or `nil` if it doesn’t exist.

```
>> a = 1
 => 1
>> defined? a
 => "local-variable"
>> defined? b
 => nil
>> defined? nil
 => "nil"
>> defined? String
 => "constant"
>> defined? 1
 => "expression"
```

As skalee commented: "It is worth noting that variable which is set to nil is initialized."

```
>> n = nil  
>> defined? n
 => "local-variable"
```

Comment: If you want to set a variable if it doesn't exist and leave it alone if it does, see @danmayer's answer (involving the `||=` operator) below.

Comment: Here's another oddity I can into.. If you define a variable in an if-block for which the condition is never met, `defined?` still returns true for a variable defined within that block!

Comment: Is there a method like `defined?` that returns boolean?

Comment: To return true/false, `!!defined?(object_name)`

Comment: @jrdioko it's not the same, i.e. setter returns false value like `nil` or `false`, defeating the purpose of caching value in instance variable, and doing all reassigning again, with god-knows-what will be executed..

Answer (score 95):

This is useful if you want to do nothing if it does exist but create it if it doesn't exist.

```
def get_var
  @var ||= SomeClass.new()
end
```

This only creates the new instance once. After that it just keeps returning the var.

Comment: This is very idiomatic Ruby too and very typical, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for this input ! I'm a ruby/rails beginner and came accross this syntax yesterday evening, had a hard time figuring out what it meant. Looks very handy !

Comment: Just don't use `||=` with boolean values, lest you feel the pain of confusion.

Comment: along with what @AndrewMarshall said, avoid this idiom with anything that might return `nil` as well unless you *really* want to evaluate the expression every time it's called when it does return `nil`

Comment: Personally don't like methods with get_ on the front (hey it's not Java :)), I'd just call it "var" and expose it to the outside world that way. I do this a lot to hide @variables and default them without having to jump through lots of hoops. get_ feels very procedural, you might want to do all sorts of things in that method one day.

Comment: No magic here. Mere syntactic sugar for `@var = @var || SomeClass.new`. Just unroll any Ruby `..=` operator if you're having difficulties wrapping your mind around it (and this is completely unrelated do `defined?` BTW). No layman rubyist should use `defined?` anyway.

Comment: If you *are* working with booleans, and want the default value to be true if the variable wasn't explicitly set to false, you can use this construction:

`var = (var or var.nil?)`

Comment: `||=` will not work for boolean `false`.
let's say 
`a = false` `a ||= true` then `a == true`
you should use `defined? a` for boolean case

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret [Sort of, not really.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505285/1863564) -- while it may not seem identical, it's worth reading the answers on that question.

Answer (score 71):

The correct syntax for the above statement is:

```
if (defined?(var)).nil? # will now return true or false
 print "var is not defined\n".color(:red)
else
 print "var is defined\n".color(:green)
end
```

substituting (`var`) with your variable. This syntax will return a true/false value for evaluation in the if statement.

Comment: That's not necessary as nil evaluates to false when used in a test

Comment: Why not `defined?(var) == nil` ?

Comment: @vol7ron - That is perfectly valid syntax.  Using the call to `.nil?` is more idiomatic, as they say.  It's more "object-oriented" to ask an object if it `nil` than to use a comparison operator.

Neither is difficult to read, so use whichever one helps you ship more product.

Comment: Which statement are you refering to ?!? Don't use an answer as a comment to something else.

Answer (score 19):

`defined?(your_var)` will work. Depending on what you're doing you can also do something like `your_var.nil?`

Comment: +1 for `your_var.nil?` because it returns true of false and is much nicer to read and write than `defined? var`. Thanks for this.

Comment: `your_var.nil?` will result in error : `undefined local variable or method your_var` when not defined before...

Answer (score 16):

Try "unless" instead of "if"

```
a = "apple"
# Note that b is not declared
c = nil

unless defined? a
    puts "a is not defined"
end

unless defined? b
    puts "b is not defined"
end

unless defined? c
    puts "c is not defined"
end
```

Comment: What does this answer add that hasn't been said by the other answers?

Comment: It very nicely answers the question in one more useful way, doesn't it?

Comment: The ruby style guide says "Favor unless over if for negative conditions" https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 12):

#### WARNING Re: A Common Ruby Pattern

the `defined?` method is the answer. [See the accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288726/4880924).

***But watch out...*** consider this common ruby pattern:

```
 def method1
    @x ||= method2
 end

 def method2
    nil
 end
```

1. `method2` always returns `nil`.
2. The first time you call `method1`, the `@x` variable is not set - therefore `method2` will be run. and
3. `method2` will set `@x` to `nil`.

But what happens the second time you call `method1`?

Remember @x has already been set to nil. But `method2` will still be run again!! If method2 is a costly undertaking this might not be something that you want.

Let the `defined?` method come to the rescue:

```
  def method1
    return @x if defined? @x
    @x = method2
  end
```

As with most things, the devil is in the implementation details.

Comment: You are totally right, thank you for highlighting that specific caveat

Answer (score 10):

Use `defined? YourVariable`
***Keep it simple silly*** .. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Here is some code, nothing rocket science but it works well enough

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rainbow'
if defined?(var).nil?  # .nil? is optional but might make for clearer intent.
 print "var is not defined\n".color(:red)
else
 print "car is defined\n".color(:green)
end
```

Clearly, the colouring code is not necessary, just a nice visualation in this toy example.

Comment: Presumably because the `nil?` is optional.

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
unless defined?(var)
  #ruby code goes here
end
=> true
```

Because it returns a boolean.

Comment: `SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):2: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND`

Comment: to use an `unless` statement seems overly complicated

Comment: `defined?` does **NOT** return a boolean, but the type of what comes afterwards. This type can be truthy or falsy, but you should pay attention. The `=> true` is misleading at best unless your "`#ruby code `" that "`goes here`" returns `true`.

Answer (score 5):

As many other examples show you don't actually need a boolean from a method to make logical choices in ruby. It would be a poor form to coerce everything to a boolean unless you actually need a boolean.

But if you absolutely need a boolean. Use !! (bang bang) or "falsy falsy reveals the truth".

```
› irb
>> a = nil
=> nil
>> defined?(a)
=> "local-variable"
>> defined?(b)
=> nil
>> !!defined?(a)
=> true
>> !!defined?(b)
=> false
```

Why it doesn't usually pay to coerce:

```
>> (!!defined?(a) ? "var is defined".colorize(:green) : "var is not defined".colorize(:red)) == (defined?(a) ? "var is defined".colorize(:green) : "var is not defined".colorize(:red))
=> true
```

Here's an example where it matters because it relies on the implicit coercion of the boolean value to its string representation.

```
>> puts "var is defined? #{!!defined?(a)} vs #{defined?(a)}"
var is defined? true vs local-variable
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

It  should be mentioned that using `defined` to check if a specific field is set in a hash might behave unexpected:

```
var = {}
if defined? var['unknown']
  puts 'this is unexpected'
end
# will output "this is unexpected"
```

The syntax is correct here, but `defined? var['unknown']` will be evaluated to the string `"method"`, so the `if` block will be executed

edit: The correct notation for checking if a key exists in a hash would be:

```
if var.key?('unknown')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note the distinction between "defined" and "assigned".

```
$ ruby -e 'def f; if 1>2; x=99; end;p x, defined? x; end;f'
nil
"local-variable"
```

x is defined even though it is never assigned!

Comment: This is something I just came across.  I was expecting `NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method`, and was confused when the only assignment/mention of the variable was in an if block that wasn't getting hit.

Answer (score 2):

`defined?` is great, but if you are in a Rails environment you can also use `try`, especially in cases where you want to check a dynamic variable name:

```
foo = 1
my_foo = "foo"
my_bar = "bar"
try(:foo)        # => 1
try(:bar)        # => nil
try(my_foo)      # => 1
try(my_bar)      # => nil
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I need the value if the var exists.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can check if it's defined while in a string via interpolation, if you code:

```
puts "Is array1 defined and what type is it? #{defined?(@array1)}"
```

The system will tell you the type if it is defined.
If it is not defined it will just return a warning saying the variable is not initialized.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving an incredibly simple example in case it helps.

When variable **doesn't exist**:

```
if defined? a then "hi" end
# => nil
```

When variable **does exist**:

```rb
a = 2
if defined? a then "hi" end
# => "hi"
```