# PHP equivalent for Ruby's or-equals (foo ||=bar)?

Tags: php, ruby, operators

In PHP I often write lines like

```
isset($foo)? NULL : $foo = 'bar'
```

In ruby there is a brilliant shortcut for that, called [or equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

```
foo ||= 'bar'
```

Does PHP have such an operator, shortcut or method call? I cannot find one, but I might have missed it.

Comment: I just want to point out that the two examples are not equivalent. `foo ||= 'bar'` in Ruby is more equivalent to `isset($foo) && !($foo === false || $foo === NULL) ? NULL : $foo = 'bar'` in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Indeed the edge cases where $foo contains "false" or null are not covered in my PHP code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of PHP7, you can use the [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary):

> The coalesce, or `??`, operator is added, which returns the result of its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, or else its second operand.

So you can write:

```
$foo = $foo ?? 'bar';
```

and it will use `$foo` if it is set and not null or assign "bar" to `$foo`.

On a sidenote, the example you give with the ternary operator should really read:

```
$foo = isset($foo) ? $foo : 'bar';
```

A ternary operation is not a shorthand if/else control structure, but *it should be used to select between two expressions depending on a third one, rather than to select two sentences or paths of execution*

Comment: Would be nice if they also added something like ??=

Comment: `??=` was [added](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator) in php 7.4.

Answer (score 9):

I really like the ?: operator. Unfortunately, it is not yet implemented on my production environment. So, if I were to make this look ruby-ish, I would go for something like:

```
isset($foo) || $foo = 'bar';
```

Or, if you want it even shorter (slower, and may yield unexpected results):

```
@$foo || $foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: What is that @ operator in the second one?

Comment: Unfortunately, `?:` still emits a notice if the variable isn't defined.

Comment: @GrowinMan @ is PHP's [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), that ignores error displaying.

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own function:

```
function setIfNotSet(&$var, $value) {
    if(!isset($var)) {
        $var = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I find it readable, concise and performant to just do:

```
isset($foo) or $foo = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3 it's possible to use `$foo ?: 'bar'`
Unless you expect $foo to be false

[edit]

Forget it. It still raises E_NOTICE if $foo is no set.

Comment: It's a real pity that this feature was implemented only since php 5.3

Comment: @Paul Dragoonis, nope.  ?: returns the first part or the second if false.  `$foo = isset($foo) ?: 'bar';` would set `$foo` to `true` if it is set, or 'bar' if it is not...  It's a great oversight in ternary usage...

Comment: I seen the PHP RFC wiki post for this inclusion into PHP 5.3 although i've never used it for 5.2 backwards compatability. Stick to good ol' fashion ternary :)

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

It's not exactly the same though. Hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No. [According to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp), that operator doesn't exist.

Also, the PHP code you posted is rather cryptic. I prefer something like this:

```
if (!isset($foo)) $foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: My code is indeed cryptic, that is exactly why I am looking for a cleaner way :).

Answer (score 1):

The most similar with ruby is this:

```
$foo or $foo = 'bar';
```

$foo is false if

```
$foo = 0;
$foo = '0';
$foo = NULL;
$foo = '';
$foo = array();
$foo = FALSE;
```

Comment: `isset($foo) or $foo = 'bar'` is equal at `$foo === NULL and $foo = 'bar'`

Comment: not quite, isset() tests if $foo is null OR if it was ever assigned a value (putting it in an equality throws an error!), but if it were ```!== NULL``` or something that may be true.