# What does ||= mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

What does `||=` mean in Ruby?

Comment: Damn, couldn't find anything when I searched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mainly used as a shortform for initializing a variable to a certain value, if it is not yet set.

Think about the statement as returning `x || (x = y)`. If `x` has a value (other than `false`), only the left side of the `||` will be evalutated (since `||` *short-circuts*), and `x` will be not be reassigned. However, if `x` is `false` or `nil`, the right side will be evaluated, which will set `x` to `y`, and `y` will be returned (the result of an assignment statement is the right-hand side).

See http://dablog.rubypal.com/2008/3/25/a-short-circuit-edge-case for more discussion.

Comment: `x ||= y` acts like `x = y unless x` which (if we assume x and y stand for arbitrary expressions and not necessarily variables) is *not* the same as either `x = x || y` (consider cases where `x = x` is not a no-op) or `x = y if x.nil?` (consider the case where x is false).

Comment: Jorg W Mittag reckons this is incorrect, in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby) to the duplicated question.

Comment: This is wrong. Please read http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660 and the links provided therein.

Comment: @Jörg et al., I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`x ||= y` is often used instead of `x = y if x == nil`

Answer (score 3):

The idea is the same as with other similar operators (`+=`, `*=`, etc):
`a ||= b` is `a = a || b`

And this trick is not limited to Ruby only: it goes through many languages with C roots.

**edit** to repel downvoters.
See one of Jörg's links for more accurate approximation, for example [this one](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2008/3/25/a-short-circuit-edge-case).
This is exactly why I don't like Ruby: nothing's ever what it seems.

Comment: Notably, not C or C++ or Java.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I mean general 'trick': producing 'a @= b' from 'a = a @ b'.

Comment: This is wrong. Please read http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660 and the links provided therein.