# what is ||= in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

what is ||= in ruby?

Comment: Why two votes to reopen? It's clearly a duplicate.

Comment: Oh my god... this question again... Are they joking?

Answer (score 0):

It's a conditional assignment. If the variable is `nil` or `false` it will be replaced with the value on the right hand side; if it already has a value other than `nil` or `false` it will keep that value.

Comment: Oops. Counter-example: `x = false; x ||= 42; x`

Comment: Oops, I missed out the `false` part. Corrected, thanks :)