# I don't understand ruby local scope

Tags: ruby

In this example,

```
def foo(x)
  if(x > 5)
    bar = 100
  end
  puts bar
end
```

Then foo(6)    Outputs: 100
and foo(3) outputs nothing.

However if i changed the definition to

```
def foo(x)
  if(x > 5)
    bar = 100
  end
  puts bob
end
```

I get an "undefined local variable or method" error.

So my question is why I am not getting this error when I call foo(3) and bar is never set?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There a couple of things going on here.  First, variables declared inside the `if` block have the same local scope as variables declared at the top level of the method, which is why `bar` is available outside the `if`.  Second, you're getting that error because `bob` is being referenced straight out of the blue. The Ruby interpreter has never seen it and never seen it initialized before.  It has, however, seen `bar` initialized before, inside the if statement.  So when is gets to bar it knows it exists.  Combine those two and that's your answer.

Comment: Thanks, yep I understood where the bob error just wasn't sure why I wasn't getting a bar error.  Do you know if I can rely on this behaviour, is it part of the specification?  For instance, can i check bar for nil after the if statement or should i really be also explicitly declaring bar = nil before the if statement?

Comment: Yes, this is reliable behavior.  Declaring bar = nil would for sure be more explicit.  But I don't know that most rubyists would do that, though.  If you keep your methods small it shouldn't be hard to understand or see where bar came from.

Answer (score 15):

Your second example is actually a red herring: the reason why you are getting an exception is not because `bob` is uninitialized, it's because it is ambiguous. It's impossible to tell whether it's a variable or a method.

Your first example works, because uninitialized local variables (as well as global variables and instance variables) evaluate to `nil`. Therefore, `puts bar` is perfectly fine: in one case `bar` is initialized to `100` and this evaluates to `100`, in the other case it is uninitialized and thus evaluates to `nil`. `puts` calls `to_s` on its argument, which is defined for `nil` (it simply returns the empty string), so everything is fine and dandy.

See also [*In Ruby, why after starting irb, foo.nil? says undefined error, and @foo.nil? gives “true”, and @@wah.nil? gives error again?*](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4021477/#4023224)

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but if this is correct, then the accepted answer by Todd presumably is not correct. He implies that the problem with bob is not that it is nil, but that it is uninitialized. The other answers suggest that you are correct.

Comment: @Jörg: Thank you so much, now you made it crystal clear to me. I wonder whether Matz is too busy to make himself as clear about this as you explained it now. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

So don't take this as gospel (since it is more based on observation then understanding), but it seems like the ruby interpreter will flag any word (without a sigil in front of it) to the left of an equals sign as a local. Your example is strange, this is even more bizarre

```
def foo
  bar = bar
  puts bar // nil, which gets coerced into ""
end
```

I don't understand why or how it works, but there you have it.

Comment: +1! JavaScript works the same way. It moves all declarations to the top and leaves assignments where they are. This can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Everything on the LHS of an assignment will get initialized to nil: `>> if false ; test = whatever ; end ; test #=> nil`. This is also how stuff like `x ||= 5` works, because it means `x = x || 5` which will be `x = nil || 5` in case x wasn't previously defined.

Comment: @jwueller Ruby doesn't move all assignments to the top though. `puts b; b = b;` results in 
``NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object``

Comment: @MichaelKohl Well, `x ||= 5` isn't necessarily equivalent to `x = x || 5` when `x` and `x=` are methods. E.g. `object.x ||= 5` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27628662/1157054). For most cases though, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

`foo(3)` doesn't output nothing. It outputs a newline.

Using `inspect` would give you more of a hint:

```
def foo(x)
  if(x > 5)
    bar = 100
  end
  puts bar.inspect
end

foo(3)
```

prints out

```
nil
```

`bar` is a fully-fledged variable, which just happens to have a value of `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Running `foo(3)` with the second definition will always give an error, since `bob` is never defined. The argument to the method doesn't change that.