# Why can I refer to a variable outside of an if/unless/case statement that never ran?

Tags: ruby

Why does the following code not throw an error?

```
if false
  x = 0
end

x  #=> nil
```

Whereas the following does throw an error:

```
y  # NameError: undefined local variable or method `y' for main:Object
```

The same thing happens with `unless` & `case` statements.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's because of how the Ruby parser works. Variables are defined by the parser, which walks through the code line-by-line, regardless of whether it will actually be executed.

Once the parser sees `x =`, it defines the local variable `x` (with value `nil`) henceforth in the current scope. Since `if`/`unless`/`case`/`for`/`while` do not create a new scope, `x` is defined and available outside the code block. And since the inner block is never evaluated as the conditional is false, `x` is not assigned to (and is thus `nil`).

Here's a similar example:

```
defined?(x) and x = 0
x  #=> nil
```

<sub>*Note that this is a rather high-level overview of what happens, and isn't necessarily exactly how the parser works.*</sub>

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with a quirk of Ruby's scoping rules.

In ruby, an undecorated variable `x` appearing by itself could either be a local variable or a method call -- the grammar can't tell which. It's up to the parser to figure it out as it resolves local variable references. The rule is simple: if an assignment to a variable of the same name has been seen already in the local scope, then the reference is a local variable, and the reference is bound to that local variable. Otherwise, it's a method call, and it will be looked up as such at runtime.

Local variable references in Ruby are optimized into array lookups (each local variable is assigned a 'slot', and bound local variable references generated by the parser are converted into slot references). The array is initialized with all `nil`:

```
/* initialize local variables */
for (i=0; i < local_size; i++) {
    *sp++ = Qnil;
}
```

Thus, if you refer to a local variable that hasn't been assigned, through a bound local reference (which can only happen if there was a skipped assignment above the reference in the same local scope), you get `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I thought your question was interesting so I tried to look it up and found this:
[I don't understand ruby local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154864/i-dont-understand-ruby-local-scope)

The correct answer seems to be put Jorg.

Lets look at what happens when you try to access a variable that isn't initialized:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `UNDECLAREDVAR' for main:Object
```

The exception states that it is unavailable to evaluate whether a variable or method. The reason it doesn't throw the same exception is because uninitialized local variables are set to nil. So `puts x` is a okay because the interpretor knows that `x` is variable but uninitialized and not a method.