# Why does Ruby seem to hoist variable declarations from inside a case statement even if that code path is not executed?

Tags: ruby

We define a function foo:

```
def foo(s)
  case s
  when'foo'
    x = 3
    puts x.inspect
  when 'bar'
    y = 4
    puts y.inspect
  end
  puts x.inspect
  puts y.inspect
end
```

We then call it as follows:

```
1.9.3p194 :017 > foo('foo')
in foo scope
3
in outer scope
3
nil
 => nil 

1.9.3p194 :018 > foo('bar')
in bar scope
3
in outer scope
nil
3
 => nil
```

Why does the function not throw an error about an unregistered local variable in either case?  In the first case, the variable `y` seems like it should not exist, so you can't call `inspect` on it in the outer scope; the same for `x` in the second case.

Here's another similar example:

```
def test1
  x = 5 if false
  puts x.inspect
end

def test2
  puts x.inspect
end
```

And then:

```
1.9.3p194 :028 > test1
nil
 => nil 

1.9.3p194 :029 > test2
NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
```

What's going on here?  It seems like Ruby is hoisting the variable declaration into the outer scope, but I wasn't aware that this is something Ruby does.  (Searching for "ruby hoisting" only turns up results about JavaScript hoisting.)

Comment: -1. In your `1.9.3p194 :018 > foo('bar')`, you should not get the result you describe.

Comment: Do you know that instead of `puts x.inspect` you can do `p x`? Much easier.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> When the Ruby parser sees the sequence  identifier, equal-sign, value,
> as in this expression
>
> ```
> x = 1
> ```
>
> it allocates space for a local variable called `x`. The creation of the
> variable—not the assignment of a value to it, but the internal
> creation of a variable—always takes place as a result of this kind of
> expression, even if the code isn’t executed!  Consider this example:
>
> ```
> if false
>   x = 1
> end
> p x # Output: nil
> p y # Fatal Error: y is unknown
> ```
>
> The assignment to `x` isn’t executed, because it’s wrapped in a failing
> conditional test. But the Ruby parser sees the sequence  `x = 1`, from
> which it deduces that the program involves a local variable `x`. The
> parser doesn’t care whether `x` is ever assigned a value. Its job is
> just to scour the code for local variables for which space needs to
> be allocated. The result is that `x` inhabits a strange kind of variable limbo.
> It has been brought into being and initialized to `nil`.
> In that respect, it differs from a variable that has no existence at
> all; as you can see in the example, examining  `x` gives you the value
> `nil`, whereas trying to inspect the non-existent variable `y` results
> in a fatal error. But although `x` exists, it has not played any role in
> the program. It exists only as an artifact of the parsing process.

**Well-Grounded Rubyist** chapter 6.1.2

Comment: Yet `x if (x = 1)` does _not_ get hoisted, but instead fails for `NoMethofError :x` (ruby 2.7.6). Is this a failure of ruby to hoist this declaration? (I know it's a bad code smell; but this came up when applying auto-formatting via prettier-ruby to a legacy code base)

Answer (score 3):

The ruby parser goes through every lines and set to nil all `variable =`. The code being actually executed or not does not matter.

See [Why can I refer to a variable outside of an if/unless/case statement that never ran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614805/weird-ruby-behaviour)