# Variable getting initialized with nil

Tags: ruby

```
p b #undefined local variable or method b for main:Object
a = nil
if a and (b=3)
  do_something_with b
end
p b # nil
```

Why is b getting the value `nil` after the execution of if block, while expected result would be  `undefined local variable or method b for main:Object`, Does Ruby initialize all the variables to `nil` in the memory beforehand ?

The same case with the following code

```
if nil
  bb = 10
end
p bb # nil
```

someone please throw some light on how ruby initializes the variables and what is going on in this case, Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Ruby seem to hoist variable declarations from inside a case statement even if that code path is not executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928050/why-does-ruby-seem-to-hoist-variable-declarations-from-inside-a-case-statement-e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[A local variable] is initialized if it appears on the left‐hand side (before the equals sign (U＋003D)) of an assignment expression, even if the expression does not actually execute. Variables of the latter sort have the value nil."

EDIT: This answer used to point to a fairly good Ruby reference, which has apparently been replaced by a malware site. I've removed the link but retained the quotation of the answer.

Comment: Appears you're right. I've removed the link, lest anyone follow it by mistake.