# Changing params in an if structure causes error (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I have a search and filter table on my index.html.erb view. Depending on what is clicked in the view, I have to change the params. What is weird though, is that I get an error even if the if statement condition isnt met.

So for example, in my code, i have:

```
if params[:checkedA] != nil
  params = someVar
end
if params[:checkedB] != nil
  #run code
else
  #run other code
end
```

When I just assign a random variable instead of params or get rid of the first if statement, it works.

```
if params[:checkedA] != nil
  foo = someOtherVar
end
if params[:checkedB] != nil
  #run code
else
  #run other code
end
```

This also works

```
if params[:checkedB] != nil
  #run code
else
  #run other code
end
```

However, even if the if statement shouldn't run, it still fails. To test it, I tried

```
if 2 < 1
  params = someVar
end
if params[:checkedB] != nil
  #run code
else
  #run other code
end
```

The error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  1: <% if 2 < 1
  2:      params = someVar
  3:    end
  4:    if params[:checkedB] != nil
  5:      #run code
  6:    else
  7:      #run other code
  app/views/quotes/quoteTable_js.js.erb:4:in `_app_views_products_product_table_js_js_erb
```

How can the if statement cause an error if it doesn't even run? Shouldn't that be the same as the statement not even being there?

Comment: Apparently params is nil. Ensure that params are not nil or check with if params && params[..]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Ruby seem to hoist variable declarations from inside a case statement even if that code path is not executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928050/why-does-ruby-seem-to-hoist-variable-declarations-from-inside-a-case-statement-e)

Comment: Ruby initializes a new local variable named `params` with `nil` (which in your case shadows the method of the same name) even if the code is not actually executed. Ruby does this for all potential assignments, irregardless if they are actually executed or not, as in Ruby, the creation of variable is a separate step from the assignment.

Comment: @HolgerJust Well I'll be darned. The more you know, I guess. If you put that in an answer, I can accept it or i'll just post my solution.

Comment: @notblakeshelton A similar question was already asked many times, hence the linked duplicate above. There's no need for an additional answer explaining the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Holger Just's comment above:

Ruby initializes a new local variable named params with nil (which in your case shadows the method of the same name) even if the code is not actually executed. Ruby does this for all potential assignments, irregardless if they are actually executed or not, as in Ruby, the creation of variable is a separate step from the assignment.