# Variables defined in If/else statement are accessible outside of if/else?

Tags: ruby

```
def foo
  #bar = nil
  if true
    bar = 1
  else
    bar = 2
  end
  bar #<-- shouldn't this refer to nil since the bar from the if statement is removed from the stack?
end

puts foo # prints "1"
```

I always thought you had to make a temporary variable and define it as nil or an initial value so that variables defined inside an if/else statement would persist outside the scope of the if/else statement and not disappear off the stack?? Why does it print 1 and not nil?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Variables are local to a function, class or module defintion, a `proc`, a block.

In ruby `if` is an expression and the branches don't have their own scope.

Also note that whenever the parser sees a variable assignment, it will create a variable in the scope, [even if that code path isn't executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928050/why-does-ruby-seem-to-hoist-variable-declarations-from-inside-a-case-statement-e):

```
def test
  if false
    a = 1
  end
  puts a
end

test
# ok, it's nil.
```

It's bit similar to JavaScript, though it doesn't hoist the variable to the top of the scope:

```
def test
  puts a
  a = 1
end

test
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for ...
```

So even if what you were saying were true, it still wouldn't be `nil`.

Comment: Up-click for for the first two sentences, though I don't believe the rest added anything pertinent to the question.

Comment: nice explanation, and the whole answer was absolutely relevant to the question, since the OP asked why the variable isn't `nil`.

Comment: It's probably worth to mention that the comparison with JavaScript is true for the `var` keyword but not for `const` and `let` which have become the recommended ways to define variables there.