# Why does a Ruby return with assignment and trailing conditional behave differently with a value assignment?

Tags: ruby

Consider method `f`,

```
def f(a)
  return a = 2 if !a.nil?
  return 'oh'
end

f(42) # 2
f(nil) # 'oh'
```

And consider method `g`,

```
def g(b)
  return a = b if !a.nil?
  return 'oh'
end

g(42) # 'oh'
g(nil) # 'oh'
```

And consider method `h`,

```
def h(b)
  a = b
  return a if !a.nil?
  return 'oh'
end

h(42) # 42
h(nil) # 'oh'
```

I expected `g(42)` to return `42` ? Why does `g(42)` not return `42` ?

What is the order of evaluation here that is the difference between `f` and `g`, and between `g` and `h`?

Comment: It is entirely contrived to provide a bare-bones, simple example to expose the problem, nothing more. Thank you for contributing an answer, and feel free to edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return a = b if !a.nil?
return 'oh'
```

is mostly equivalent to

```
if !a.nil?
  return a = b
end
return 'oh'
```

As such, Ruby first tests whether `a` is not nil (which is false because `a` is in fact `nil` there as it had not been assigned a value yet). Because of that, the body of the `if` is not executed and the execution follows along to the `return 'oh'`.

The more important question here is however: why did this work at all and did not result in an error such as

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a'

when trying to access the `a` variable in the `if`, even though it was not initialized before.

This works because Ruby initializes variables with `nil` if they appear on the left-hand side of an assignment in the code, even though the variable may not actually be assigned. This behavior is further explained in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928261/421705.

Following this logic, your code thus only works with your original inline-`if` but would fail with the block-form `if` as with this longer form, `a` would only be initialized within the `if` block. Here, you would thus get the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I see where I messed up. Function f's parameter is named `a`, so it is not nil. This really threw me off. Had I defined `def f(b)`, I would have observed the expected behavior. Human fault again!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of lexical parsing as [@HolgerJust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just) pointed out.

There are some other similarly interesting side effects of using the *modifier-[if/unless]*

```
def a; 1; end; 
(a if a = true) == a 
#=> false
```

Here's how the parser sees it in a nutshell:

1. Define a method `a()`
2. The parser then encounters `a` as part of the *then* body so it tags this `a` as a method call (`a()`) because `a` is not a local variable at this point and the ruby syntax allows for omission of parentheses in method calls.
3. The parser then encounters the *test expression* and here it marks `a` as a local variable, due to the assignment (`=`)
4. The *test expression* is executed and in process it assigns `a` the value of `true` and the test passes
5. The *then* body is now executed which calls the `a()` method, because this is how the reference `a` was identified in #2, which causes this expression `(a if a = true)` to return `1`.
6. However as pointed out in #4 the assignment to `a` has also occurred so this comparison becomes `(1) == true`

**Note:** If you remove the method definition this will raise a `NameError` because of #2 however the local variable assignment will still occur.

```
begin 
  c if c = 1 
rescue NameError 
  puts 'Oh' 
  c
end == c and c == 1 
# 'Oh'
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> def g(b)
>   return a = b if !a.nil?
>   return 'oh'
> end
>
> g(42) # 'oh'
> g(nil) # 'oh'
> ```
>
> I expected g(42) to return 42 ? Why does g(42) not return 42 ?

There are several potential reasons but the more important question to answer first is this; Why were you expecting 42?

1. Is it because you thought `a` was already being explicitly defined in the prior method definition and so it should already have some value?  If so, it should be noted that methods starting with a lower case letter are `local variables` that cannot be accessed outside the method in which they are defined.  I'm assuming that this is not your issue and that you already have a proper understanding of variable scope.  I thought it might be worth mentioning though just in case--especially for other users who might have a similar problem in the future.
2. Is it because you thought `a` was *implicitly* being assigned a value other than nil?  If so, its not.  You need to define `a` before you can test against it.  As mentioned by others, you should have probably expected an error if anything since you can't even test against `a` to see whether or not its `nil` unless it was already defined.

I can't see any logical reason why someone would expect to see `42` outside those 2 scenarios but maybe I'm missing something.

> What is the order of evaluation here that is the difference between f
> and g, and between g and h?Why is `a` always evaluating to anything
> other than nil (`!nil?`) ?

Method `g` has already been discussed by myself and others. The only reason it works at all instead of throwing an error though is because `a` is being implicitly assigned a value of nil by lexical parsing/order of operations (see answers already posted by others).

Method `f` is using a `parameter` named `a` so `a` is being explicitly defined before you test against it.

Method `h` is also explicitly defining `a` (`a = b` and **not** `a = b if`) before testing against it.