# How do you set a boolean default value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For other types of variables, I use `||=`, but this doesn't work for booleans (`x ||= true` assigns x to true even if x was previously assigned to false).

I'd thought that this would work:

```
x = true unless defined?(x)
```

But it doesn't: it assigns x to nil for some reason. (An explanation here would be appreciated.)

I do know one method that works:

```
unless defined?(x)
  x = true
end
```

But it's rather verbose. Is there a more concise way to assign default values to boolean variables in Ruby?

Comment: is there a reason why you do not want x to be assigned to nil (which is equivalent to false for all intent and purposes) ?

Comment: @sylvain.joyeux Because he wants it to be `true`, not falsey.

Comment: @sylvain.joyeux Using nil instead of false is fine, but it doesn't address the trouble with `||=`. If you try to assign a default value to x using `||=`, and x was previously assigned to nil, it will be overridden rather than retaining the value of nil (since nil is falsey).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must have `defined?` *first*, else the parser reaches `x =` and then defines `x` (which makes it `nil`) before running the `unless`:

```
defined?(x) or x = true
x  #=> true
```

```
x = false
defined?(x) or x = true
x  #=> false
```

Doing a `if`/`unless` block (instead of post-`if`/`unless` one-liner) also works:

```
unless defined?(x)
  x = true
end
x  #=> true
```

```
x = false
unless defined?(x)
  x = true
end
x  #=> false
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch again with the same [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614805/weird-ruby-behaviour/12615158#12615158) once again with a better explanation.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja I knew I'd wrote up something about this recently…

Answer (score 3):

There are only two *non-true* values in Ruby: `false` and `nil`. All you need to do is differentiate between those. Until the new `//=` operator that does this automatically comes around, you're stuck with this:

```
if (x.nil?)
  x = true
end
```

Hopefully this can be abbreviated in future versions of ruby. 99% of the time you don't really care about the difference between the two non-true values, but that 1% of the time you do it becomes annoying to have to be so unusually verbose.

Remember that the `defined?` operator will always return `"local-variable"` for that condition because the variable `x` is "defined" as a local variable. Contrast with `defined?(nope)` and you'll get `nil` because that variable does not exist. Ruby is concerned with the variable or constant in question, not if that variable or constant has been *defined* with a value.

Comment: Or `x = true if x.nil?`, which to me is more readable than the `||=` idiom anyway!

Comment: I know this might seem obvious but you need to have `x` somewhere in your code because `class A; def self.check; if x.nil?; x = true; end; end; end; A.check;` will return an `undefined local variable` exception.

Comment: Depending on the cotext of the poster, this might actually be wrong. If you do this in IRB, it causes an `undefined local variable` exception where as the working example the poster does not and assigns `x = true`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your example is only good if x hasn't been previously defined. Otherwise, it fails with `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'x' for main:Object`. In my case, it's uncertain whether x will be previously defined, which is why I was checking with `defined?`. Sorry if this was unclear in the question.

Comment: Yeah, you have to define variables somewhere before using them. It's better to use instance variables like `@x` which can't not exist.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = defined?(x) ? true  : false
```

Comment: -1 This will make `x` be `false` even if it was already `true`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall did you mean to say it would make `x` be `true` even if it was already `false`?

Comment: @evanrmurphy Yes, I reversed the two.