# Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?

Tags: ruby, boolean, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

Forgive me if this is a newbie question but I'm reading a book on rails where the writer used this expression in a helper method:

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
```

Is this use of double pipes still a Boolean OR statement?

If so how does it work?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's a conditional assignment. From [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators):

```
 x = find_something() #=>nil
 x ||= "default"      #=>"default" : value of x will be replaced with "default", but only if x is nil or false
 x ||= "other"        #=>"default" : value of x is not replaced if it already is other than nil or false
```

Comment: This is a great example of chaining them together!

Answer (score 19):

The code `foo ||= bar` is almost equivalent to `foo = foo || bar`. In Ruby (as in many languages, like JavaScript or Io) boolean operators are "guard" operators. Instead of always returning `true` or `false`, they evaluate to the value of the first operand that evaluates to a "truthy" value.

For example, this code `foo = 1 || delete_all_files_from_my_computer()` will not delete anything: foo will be set to `1` and the second operand *won't even be evaluated*.

In Ruby, the only "non-truthy" values are `nil` and `false`. So the code `foo ||= bar` will only evaluate `bar` and set `foo` to the result if `foo` is `nil` or `false`.

As instance variables default to `nil` when not set, code like `@foo ||= bar` is a common Ruby idiom to set the instance variable if it has not already been set.

Comment: This is wrong. `foo ||= bar` is *somewhat* equivalent to `foo || foo = bar` and *not* `foo = foo || bar` (as has been discussed a dozen times on StackOverflow already, and about a million times on the Ruby mailinglists), but only somewhat. An *exact* expansion of `||=` has still not been found, and I personally am doubtful that `||=`'s semantics *can* even be expressed in Ruby *at all*. The clearest description I have seen so far of how `||=` works, is the evaluation algorithm given in the ISO Draft Ruby Language Specification, except that I am almost convinced that algorithm is *wrong*.

Comment: "I personally am doubtful that ||='s semantics can even be expressed in Ruby at all." It's probably either Bocce or the binary code of moisture evaporators.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This is precisely why I wrote _"almost exactly equivalent"_ instead of _"equivalent"_ or _"the same as"_. For a newcomer who doesn't understand `||=`, the simple mental model that matches other `?=` compound assignment operators is sufficient. I have, nonetheless, removed the word _"exactly_" from my answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can think of it as short for:

```
@current_user = @current_user || User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
```

`@current_user` gets evaluated first, if it is non-null then the OR short-circuits, returning the value of @current_user, and not calling User.find_by_id.

(This works only because Ruby treats null as false, and non-null as true, in a boolean context. It doesn't work for languages like Java that don't treat non-booleans as truthy.)

Comment: Ah thanks for the extra explanation.. Ruby is such a beautiful language!

Comment: The "OR" certainly does _not_ "return" `true`! It _evaluates_ to the **value of `@current_user`** if non-`nil` and non-`false`.

Comment: @Phrogz: yes, you're right, tried to correct this.