# What does the "||=" operand stand for in ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

I tested like this:

```
>> a||=3
=> 3
>> a
=> 3
>> a||=b
=> 3
>> b
NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
    from (irb):11
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/), [what is ||= in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3945711/), [Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4500375/), [Is the ruby operator ||= intelligent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2989862/) and probably many others as well. [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/) is even linked to in the *Related Questions* tab. Plus, there is [The definitive list of ||= (OR Equal) threads and pages](http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660/).

Comment: Damn, there's *another* one, even with the *exact same title* as one of the others: [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3800957/).

Comment: Why I didn't see them on the reminder pane when I posted this...

Comment: @Ikahtz: Possibly because the reminder pane doesn't utilize tags, and therefore had more links to questions with "ruby" in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the shorthand for a logical OR operation.  It is equivalent to:

```
a || a = b
```

Note: The above code sample has been corrected to reflect the true (if unintuitive) behavior if expanding `a ||= b`.  Thanks to the people who pointed that out for me.  [Here is the source](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2008/3/25/a-short-circuit-edge-case)

if `a` evaluates to true it will remain as is, otherwise `b` will be assigned to `a`. In ruby `nil` evaluates to `false`, so you can see how this is useful for lazy loading and default value assignment.

Comment: thanks dude~ helps me clear the fog~~

Comment: No problem.  When you want to know what `*` does when used in front of an array or in a method call/signature, search for "ruby splat operator".  Maybe you already know, but I remember that one taking me a while to find (searching for "*" is not easy).

Comment: Exactly Ed!! I searched on google and it simply ignore all such operands (even I quote/doublequote them). This is cooool~ Thanks man!!

Comment: This is wrong, as has been discussed a gazillion times already here on StackOverflow, on the Ruby mailing list, and on pretty much every Ruby blog ever created.

Comment: @ Jörg W Mittag: Thanks for that link, there's some interesting stuff there.  I am not a Ruby expert, but I don't see what is "wrong" here.  There are nuances that I didn't explain (or know about), but you seem to have woken up on the wrong side of the bed today.  I use Ruby for simple stuff, most of the code that I write is inherently low level and not suitable for Ruby.

Comment: For all downvoters: Still awaiting an explanation of what is wrong here.  Don't get me wrong, it's not the downvotes that I care about, I would like to know what I've missed.  You don't help when you pass through, say something is wrong without explaining, and then move on.

Comment: @Ed S. - If you browse the duplicates, you'll find [A short-circuit (||=) edge case](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2008/3/25/a-short-circuit-edge-case). Summarized: `a||=b` does not expand to `a=a||b` but `a||a=b`. It's a subtle difference but does represent different behavior as described in the article.

Comment: @Corbin March - Ahh, ok, that's what I was looking for (I was browsing the ruby-forum archives). Thanks. That is an odd behavior (intuitively) to be sure.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, the only thing I was 'complaining' about were downvotes that don't explain what is "wrong".  Like I just said, I went through some of the posts on ruby-forum and didn't see what Corbin linked to, which is all that was needed.  I couldn't care less about rep, but I do want to learn new things.  This Jorg guy just ran through, left jerky comments, and linked to about 6 posts.  I don't have time to read all of them, a simple link to a relevant topic or a simple "it expands to `a || b = a` would have been sufficient.

Comment: Oh, looks like Andrew deleted his comment.  So sad.

Comment: @Ed S.: Yes, I deleted my comment. I was a bit annoyed at your comments, but then I changed my mind and decided to leave it alone.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I swear I really just wanted to know what was wrong in my post for my own education, I don't care about downvotes if they are warranted :)