# Ruby: Can someone elaborate this code?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

```
  class Person
    attr_accessor :name

    class << self
      attr_accessor :instances

      def instances
        @instances ||= []
        @instances
      end
    end

    def initialize( name )
      Person.instances << self
      @name = name
    end

  end

  joe = Person.new( "Joe" )
  zach = Person.new( "Zach" )

  puts "You have #{Person.instances.size} people in existance!" POINT C

  class Paramedic < Person

    def initialize( name )
      super( name )
      Paramedic.instances << self
    end
 end

  sally = Paramedic.new( "Sally" )
  puts "You have #{Person.instances.size} people in existance!" #POINT B
  puts "You have #{Paramedic.instances.size} paramedics in existance!" POINT C
```

What do these lines do?

```
@instances ||= []
Person.instances << self
Paramedic.instances << self
```

Comment: How about you have a go at describing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is class level variable `@instances`.

First line

```
@instances ||= []
```

initialise this variable by empty array if `@instances` is nil.

Then during initialisation of instance of class Person code `Person.instances << self` add this instance to array of all instances of class Person.

So if you call `Person.instances` you will give all instances of class Person.

Same situation with Paramedic.

Comment: Why is || used ? why not @instances = []

Comment: Because that would reset @instances every time `instances` accessor is called. In other words calling `Person.instances` would always return `[]`

Comment: If you don't use || you will get [] at the start of all initialisations

Comment: Because doing that would always assign `@instances` with an empty array. As already explained in the answers, `||=` assigns the right side only if left side is `nil`. Note that `@instances` is part of _class_ `Person`, *not* part of instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

This code essentially keeps track of instances of `Person` and `Paramedic`. Each time one of these is constructed, the created object is added to the list represented by the class variable `instances`. `self` refers to the instance itself in this case.

`@instances ||= []` is a Ruby idiom that is short for `@instances = @instances || []`. Because in Ruby only `false` and `nil` evaluate to `false`, the snippet either returns `@instances` or an empty list if `@instances` does not yet exist.