# Ruby equivalent of Groovy's Elvis (?:) operator?

Tags: ruby, groovy

I know I can live without it, but the question's been bugging me.

Is there a Ruby idiom that's equivalent to Groovy's [Elvis operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator%28%3F%3A%29) (`?:`)?

Essentially, I want to be able to shorten this

```
PARAM = ARGV[0] ? ARGV[0] : 'default'
```

Or equivalently

```
PARAM = 'default' unless PARAM = ARGV[0]
```

Into something like this

```
PARAM = ARGV[0] ?: 'default'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Only if you already know the answer :p

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Never mind :-) I just found the answer myself after finding out the name of the operator.

From [here](http://log4p.com/2007/12/19/how-elvis-showed-me-a-neat-way-of-using-operators-in-ruby/):

```
PARAM = ARGV[0] || 'default'
```

(Must be 'cause I'm juggling 4 languages right now so I forgot I could do that in the first place.)

Comment: Alternatively, if you're doing something like `@params = @params || 5 `you can shorten it to `@params ||= 5`

Comment: @RyanBigg: To be pedantic, it's more like `@params || @params = 5`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby/2505285#2505285

Comment: This is sadly not entirely true. Kotlin's `?:` and C#'s `??` check for NULLITY. Ruby's `||` checks for truth-iness. If you are working with booleans, let's say `foo = bar || true` and you are expecting `true` to be the default only if `bar` is `nil`, it won't work. If `bar` is not `nil` but `false`, it will still default to `true`.

Answer (score 12):

Possible since Ruby `2.3`.

```
dog&.owner&.phone
```

Comment: It solves a different problem, but this gets around the `null`-ity vs `true`-thy conundrum:, `nil.class # => NilClass`, `nil&.class # => nil (not NilClass!)`, `false.class #=> FalseClass`, `false&.class #=> FalseClass`

Answer (score 4):

Isn't `PARAM = ARGV[0] ? ARGV[0] : 'default'` the same as `PARAM = (ARGV[0] || 'default')` ?

Comment: Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816032/ruby-equivalent-of-groovys-elvis-operator#comment98655983_7816041). It's not exactly the same.

Comment: @Adeynack, it seems like both syntaxes @Hock mentioned would branch based on the truthiness of `ARGV[0]`. If I'm wrong, can you explain which one would not and why?

Comment: @JakeRobb, you are totally right and I am now wondering why I wrote that 3 years ago. Thanks for getting the confusion I introduced out!