# '||=' operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Could some one explain to me the meaning of the following Ruby code? (I saw this code snippet in one guy's project):

```
car ||= (method_1 || method_2 || method_3 || method_4)
```

What is the difference between the above code and the following code?

```
car = method_1 || method_2 || method_3 || method_4
```

**----------update--------------**

Ok, I got the meaning of `||=` operator after read @Dave's explanation, my **next question** is if both `method_2`, `method_3` and `method_4` return a value, which one's value will be assigned to `car`? (I suppose `car` is **nil** initially)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Duplicate: [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/), [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3800957/), [what is `||=` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3945711/), [Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4500375/), [What does the “`||=`” operand stand for in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5124930/), [what does a `||=` mean in Ruby language?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5230162/), [Is the ruby operator `||=` intelligent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2989862/), …

Comment: … [What does `||=` mean?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7556902/), [What does “`||=`” do in Ruby 1.9.2?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7714803/), and probably many others as well. See also [The definitive list of `||=` (OR Equal) threads and pages](http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660/).

Comment: Regarding your edit: `||` and `&&` short circuit, which in case of `||` means evaluation stops as soon as a truthy (not `nil` or `false`) value is encountered, whereas `&&` stops as soon as it finds a falsey value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an assignment operator for 'Conditional Assignment'

See here -> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators

Conditional assignment:

```
 x = find_something() #=>nil
 x ||= "default"      #=>"default" : value of x will be replaced with "default", but only if x is nil or false
 x ||= "other"        #=>"default" : value of x is not replaced if it already is other than nil or false
```

Operator ||= is a shorthand form of the expression:

```
x = x || "default"
```

EDIT:

After seeing OP's edit, the example is just an extension of this, meaning:

```
car = method_1 || method_2 || method_3 || method_4
```

Will assign the first non-nil or non-false return value of method_1, method_2, method_3, method_4 (in that order) to `car` or it'll retain its old value.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit different from others, but I kind like your explanation because you have pointed out the key point of using this operator (conditional assignment). Though it is better if you can also mention x||= Y is equal to x=x||y

Comment: Please check my update, I have a new question regards to the operator.

Comment: Hey, glad I've helped - I've edited my answer to include a little extra - hopefully it'll address your first comment and your questions update.

Comment: @ Dave, have you checked my update in my post, I have a new question which yields after read your answer. In general, I would like to know if several methods return value, which one's value will be assigned to the left-hand side variable? What is the rule for that?

Comment: It'll be the leftmost non-nil or non-false value (if none meet this criteria, 'car' will keep its original value) - as above.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I got what I prefer to know.

Comment: Be careful, `a ||= b` is not strictly equivalent to `a = a || b`. http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Answer (score 4):

```
car ||= (method_1 || method_2)
```

is equivalent to

```
car = (car || (method_1 || method_2))
```

In general,

```
x op= y
```

means

```
x = x op y
```

Comment: @Leem.fin: You see my edit as well. `car ||= anything` means `car = car || anything`

Comment: Oh! I see. I thought it will '||' with all the possible combinations with the right side part of '=' sign that's why I add more methods .

Comment: @ Armen, what do you think about @Dave's explanation

Comment: Dave shows the ||= operator in action: once it has been invoked on the first line, x contains a 'non-falsy' value and the second line does nothing.

Comment: -1. This is wrong. `a ||= b` is much more like `a || a = b` than `a = a || b`, although it is in fact not equivalent to *either one* of those.

Answer (score 3):

the `||=` operator checks first, if your value `car` is already set. If `car` returns nil, it will assign the first value on the right side which doesn't return `nil` or `false`.

So, given your example from above, if you assign a value to car like

```
car = "BMW"
```

and you execute you code-snippet, the value of car will still  be "BMW";

If method_1 returns (for instance) the String `"Value from Method 1"` and car is `nil` or `false`, then car this String will be assigned to car

```
car = nil
car ||= (method_1 || method_2)
car # => "Value from Method 1"
```

If method_1 also returns `nil`/`false`, it will check for the value in method_2, and so forth, until it gets some sort of true-value

The difference to your second code-snippet is, that in case of `||=` the variable `car` will be evaluated first, and set if it returns nil or false.

If you use `=`only, no evaluation will happen and car will be set to the first value on the right that doesn't return nil or false.

-- UPDATE --

To answer your update question, the value on the right side will be evaluated from left to right, so the first one  that doesn't return `nil` or `false` will be assigned.

```
car = nil
# method_1 => "nil"
# method_2 => "false"
# method_3 => "value method 3"
# method_4 => "I won't be called"

car ||= (method_1 || method_2 || method_3 || method_4)
# => "value method 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
car ||= (method_1 || method_2 || method_3 || method_4)
```

car will retain its value after this statement is run, if car initially is not nil.

If car was nil before this statement, the first non nil value to return from method_1, method_2, ... will be assigned to car.

---

```
car = method_1 || method_2 || method_3 || method_4
```

In this case, car will be re-assigned the first non nil value to return out of the methods even if car already has a non nil value before this statement ran

Answer (score 0):

> car ||= (method_1 || method_2)

is equal to

> car = car || (method_1 || method_2)

Comment: -1. This is wrong. `a ||= b` is much more like `a || a = b` than `a = a || b`, although it is in fact not equivalent to *either one* of those.

Answer (score 0):

in short it's equal to:

```
car = car || method_1 || method_2
```

in more details, it's a bit more complex:

```
car = (defined?(car) && car) || (method_1 || method_2)
```

in any case, what comes after the `||=` will **only** be executed if `car`:

- is not yet defined
- is `false`
- is `nil`

Answer (score 0):

answer to update:

method_2 gets assigned since it is the first non-false, non-nil value in the list.