# What is ||= in rails?

Tags: ruby

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  # Finds the User with the ID stored in the session with the key
  # :current_user_id This is a common way to handle user login in
  # a Rails application; logging in sets the session value and
  # logging out removes it.
  def current_user
    @_current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] &&
      User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
  end
end
```

How to understand the code above? What does `||=` mean? And is `@_current_user` an id or a user object? Also, why it starts with `_`?

Can anyone answer me what `@_current_user` is?

Comment: That post's answer is not good. And it does not answer my other questions about `@_current_user`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506257/operator-in-ruby - search for "ruby operators".

Answer (score 1):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby), `a ||= b` is shorthand for `a || a = b`.

And regarding the value of `@_current_user`, if we assume `session[:current_user_id]` is `5`, then the `&&` operator with the User model will return the User instance:

```
> 5 && User.new(:name => 'Foo')
=> #<User name="Foo">
```

So `@_current_user` will be the User instance.

Comment: in simply says,
it just fetches data from the database to avoid hitting the database again and again for each request, we just decide if @_currentuser already fetched just return, if not go and just fetch and return.