# What does the '||=' operator do in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

I'm new to ruby and I saw this being used in one of the answers here:

`RACK_ENV = ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] ||= 'test'`

I couldn't find any reference to the `||=` operator...

Comment: Indeed it is - didn't show up in search :/

Comment: I got lucky -- it was near the top of the _Related_ list on the right side; but you might want to consider the [Symbol Hound Search Engine](http://symbolhound.com/?q=||%3D) when you need to search for symbols in the future. I don't know how they do it but it's been supremely useful at things Google absolutely fails at.

Comment: Wow, now that IS useful, thanks!

Comment: Spread the good word. :) I've spent years cursing at Google's inability to do simple token searches and to finally have a solution that's magically right most of the time is pretty awesome. :)

Comment: Duplicate: [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/), [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3800957/), [what is `||=` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3945711/), [Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4500375/), [What does the “`||=`” operand stand for in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5124930/), [what does a `||=` mean in Ruby language?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5230162/), [Is the ruby operator `||=` intelligent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2989862/), …

Comment: … [What does `||=` mean?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7556902/), [What does “`||=`” do in Ruby 1.9.2?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7714803/) ['`||=`' operator in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/8506257/), and probably many others as well. See also [The definitive list of `||=` (OR Equal) threads and pages](http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

what does || do? If you have a and b then `a || b` is true if and only if either a or b is true. It is the same with ||= this operator combines two operations '=' and '||'. So `a ||= b` is equivelent to `c || c = b`

EDIT: so in your context ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] ||= 'test' means that if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] is not nil and not false it will preserve its value, otherwise it will become 'test' and after that the new value of ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] is assigned to RACK_ENV

Comment: In fact it's `c || c = b`. If c is truthy, no assignment is done at all. This is an important difference when it's actually used the way it is used most of the time, i.e. as a optional initializer.

Comment: -1. This is wrong, as has been explained to death a gazillion times here on StackOverflow and on the Ruby mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

here is the article which explains it really good.

« Ruby, concurrency,... | Main | How does one update... » 
The curious case of the Ruby T-Square operator. 
By prashant on Dec 14, 2008
 The "||=" operator is interesting, both in what it does as much as in how it's widely used in Ruby land.  The operator does not do what you would usually expect.  i.e.,

a ||= expr

is not the same as

a = a || expr

The evaluation happens to be

a or a = expr

and the difference is important in at least one use case [0]

As a little DTrace script will verify, this operator is not implemented is a method(or anywhere in Ruby land) and is intrinsic to the VM.   The reason is performance, and the fact that the entire expression does not have to be evaluated to yield a result when you're 'OR'ing:

"Ruby's Boolean operators are built into the language and are not based on methods: classes, for example, cannot define their own && method.  Ruby defines special true and false values but does not have a Boolean type. method. The reason for this is that Boolean operators can be applied to any value and must behave consistently for any kind of operand."

. . .

"Another reason that Ruby's Boolean operators are a core part of the language rather than redefinable methods is that the binary operators are "short-circuiting." If the value of the operation is completely determined by the lefthand operand, then the righthand operand is ignored and is never even evaluated."

https://blogs.oracle.com/prashant/entry/the_ruby_t_square_operator