# How does "||=" work?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= (or equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

I am learning Ruby and got confused with following code. I can understand what it does but can't understand how this work exactly.

```
h = Hash.new
h['key1'] ||= 'value1'
=> "value1"

p h
=> {"key1"=>"value1"}
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) article for an exhaustive explanation.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Specially to KL-7. The article make my understanding very clear.

Comment: @charles The article that you say made it clear shows that the answer you accepted is incorrect, so why did you accept it?

Comment: Duplicate: [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/995593/), [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3800957/), [what is `||=` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3945711/), [Double Pipe Symbols in Ruby Variable Assignment?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4500375/), [What does the “`||=`” operand stand for in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5124930/), [what does a `||=` mean in Ruby language?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5230162/), [Is the ruby operator `||=` intelligent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2989862/), …

Comment: … [What does `||=` mean?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7556902/), [What does “`||=`” do in Ruby 1.9.2?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7714803/) ['`||=`' operator in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/8506257/), [What does the '`||=`' operator do in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/9698946/), and probably many others as well. See also [The definitive list of `||=` (OR Equal) threads and pages](http://Ruby-Forum.Com/topic/151660/). Seriously, when will the broken search function get fixed? Guys, it's been four years now!

Answer (score 0):

Given a `Hash`:

```
hash = {}
```

This expression:

```
hash[:key] ||= :value
```

Expands to:

```
hash[:key] || hash[:key] = :value
```

Ruby's logical operators [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which means that `hash[:key] = :value` will only be executed if, and only if, `hash[:key]` is either `false` or `nil`.

If it is anything else, its value alone will be sufficient to determine the result of the [logical disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), and the rest of the expression will not be evaluated.

This is *fundamentally* different than:

```
hash[:key] = hash[:key] || :value
```

In this case, the `[]=` method will be called either way, and the only difference is which argument it will receive: `:value` if `hash[:key]` is either `false` or `nil`, or the value of `hash[:key]` itself otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

It's an *abbreviated assignment pseudooperator*. There are eleven of them; the most usual one is:

```
x += y #expands to x = x+y
```

`||=` goes the same way:

```
x ||= y expands to x = x||y
```

It works for +, -, *, /, %, **, &&, ||, &, |, ^, <<, >>.

Comment: This is **wrong**. Please see [What does ||= mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: While your reasoning _is_ correct, the conclusion is false, as noted by Andrew Marshall. `x ||= y` actually expands to `x || x = y`. The subtle difference is that _no assignment will take place if `x` is either `false` or `nil`_.

Comment: @Andrew Hmm, I wrote this with page 96 of The Ruby Programming Language (Flanagan and Matsomoto) as reference. The expansion `x=x||y` is mentioned there, in a table. In a block of text it is noted that it behaves slightly different in the case of the lvalue being not false or nil (no assignment).

Comment: @steenslag Interesting. There's plenty of discussion as to why it's not that (with code to back it up) mentioned in the other question, as well as a good post on [Ruby Inside](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html). Ultimately it's not *exactly* equivalent to either `a || a = b` or `a ||= b`.

Answer (score -2):

the default value in `Hash.new` is `nil`

so `h['key1'] ||= 'value1'` works as 
"if key='key1' has no corresponding value yet, let the value be 'value1' "

Comment: That's not entirely true. `h['key1'] = false; h['key1'] ||= 42; h['key1'] #=> 42`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall sorry but are something conflicting?

Comment: Yes. I assigned a value to `h['key']`, then did an `||=` to it, but it got the value from `||=`. Your answer states that this should only happen "if key1 has no corresponding value yet", but I just showed a case where it does when there is a value already.

Comment: That is possible, but I only meant to explain what happened in the given code.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that your explanation is incorrect. To further confuse things you say there is a "default value", but then say that `||=` only does something if there is "no corresponding value". Which implies that `||=` is essentially a no-op, which it isn't.