# RoR: Meaning of "user ||= User.new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= (or equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

[Out on the internet](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorials-rails-bootstrap-devise-cancan.html) I've seen the following syntax in Ruby/Rails:

```
user ||= User.new
```

I'm a newbie and I can't parse this.  Can someone explain to me what the "||=" operator does?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I tried putting '||=' into the search box here on SO but nothing came up. Maybe my query was being interpreted as a couple of boolean operators rather than a string?  Am I searching the wrong way?

Comment: I am not sure how SO handles characters like ||=. I searched using the English words or equals.

Comment: I'll try that next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `user` is already set this does nothing, otherwise it will assign a new `User` object (created with `User.new`).

[According to David A. Black](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/y1Maaqk_Q7c%5B1-25%5D), author of "The Well-Grounded Rubyist":

> x ||= y means:  x || x = y
>
> The difference is that x ||= y won't complain if x is undefined,
>   whereas if you type x || x = y and there's no x in scope, it will.

For some added details, here's the relevant part of [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y):

```
| var_lhs tOP_ASGN command_call
{
  /*%%%*/
  value_expr($3);
  if ($1) {
    ID vid = $1->nd_vid;
    if ($2 == tOROP) {
      $1->nd_value = $3;
      $$ = NEW_OP_ASGN_OR(gettable(vid), $1);
      if (is_asgn_or_id(vid)) {
        $$->nd_aid = vid;
      }
    }
    else if ($2 == tANDOP) {
      $1->nd_value = $3;
      $$ = NEW_OP_ASGN_AND(gettable(vid), $1);
    }
    else {
      $$ = $1;
      $$->nd_value = NEW_CALL(gettable(vid), $2, NEW_LIST($3));
    }
  }
```

`NEW_OP_ASGN_OR` is defined in `node.h`:

```
#define NEW_OP_ASGN_OR(i,val) NEW_NODE(NODE_OP_ASGN_OR,i,val,0)
```

`NEW_NODE` looks like this:

```
#define NEW_NODE(t,a0,a1,a2) rb_node_newnode((t),(VALUE)(a0),(VALUE)(a1),(VALUE)(a2))
```

Looking for `NODE_OP_ASGN_OR` leads to `compile.c`, where the interesting part looks like this:

```
case NODE_OP_ASGN_OR:{
   LABEL *lfin = NEW_LABEL(nd_line(node));
   LABEL *lassign;

   if (nd_type(node) == NODE_OP_ASGN_OR) {
     LABEL *lfinish[2];
     lfinish[0] = lfin;
     lfinish[1] = 0;
     defined_expr(iseq, ret, node->nd_head, lfinish, Qfalse);
     lassign = lfinish[1];
     if (!lassign) {
       lassign = NEW_LABEL(nd_line(node));
     }
     ADD_INSNL(ret, nd_line(node), branchunless, lassign);
   }
   else {
     lassign = NEW_LABEL(nd_line(node));
   }

   COMPILE(ret, "NODE_OP_ASGN_AND/OR#nd_head", node->nd_head);
   ADD_INSN(ret, nd_line(node), dup);

   if (nd_type(node) == NODE_OP_ASGN_AND) {
     ADD_INSNL(ret, nd_line(node), branchunless, lfin);
   }
   else {
     ADD_INSNL(ret, nd_line(node), branchif, lfin);
   }

   ADD_INSN(ret, nd_line(node), pop);
   ADD_LABEL(ret, lassign);
   COMPILE(ret, "NODE_OP_ASGN_AND/OR#nd_value", node->nd_value);
   ADD_LABEL(ret, lfin);

   if (poped) {
     /* we can apply more optimize */
     ADD_INSN(ret, nd_line(node), pop);
   }
   break;
 }
```

I think this is more than I ever wanted to know about assignment in Ruby, but it was rather entertaining to look this up.

Comment: x ||= y means: x = x || y

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a shortcut for:

```
user = user || User.new
```

or for better understanding:

```
if user.nil?
    user = User.new
end
```

I bet you've seen similar notations before with operators like '+'

```
i += 1
```

which can also be written out as:

```
i = i + 1
```

Comment: Not only `nil`, also `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The statement set `user` to itself (if it is already an existing object) or `User.new` (which will create a new user if user is null). It's a logical OR that will avoid having an assigned null user object.

The code is a shorthand for

```
user = user || User.new
```

If user is null, then user will be set to `User.new`.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is equivalent to

```
user = user || User.new
```

which is equivalent of

```
user = user ? user : User.new
```

It will assign the value of `User.new` to the variable `user` if and only if `user` is *nil*. If it isn't, the contents of `user` will remain unchanged.

Comment: Same here, `nil` or `false`, not only `nil`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but if they aren't familiar with `||=`, I wouldn't expect them to be familiar with `?:`

Comment: Why? Lots of languages feature a ternary operator, not all of them have `||=`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Of course you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to `user = user || User.new`.

This relies on the short-circuiting behavior of the `||` operator.  If the left side of the expression is true, then it doesn't matter what the right side will be, the overall expression will be true, so the operator "short-circuits" and stops evaluating.  And rather than returning a boolean "true", the `||` operator returns the last value that it evaluated.

So, `||=` is useful for assigning a default value.  If `user` has a value, then `user || User.new` evaluates to `user` otherwise it evaluates to `User.new` which is the default value.

An equivalent block would be:

```
if user
    user = user
else 
    user = User.new
end
```