# What is the purpose ||= in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= (or equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)
>   [RoR: Meaning of “user ||= User.new”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958708/ror-meaning-of-user-user-new)

I saw it used in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth):

```
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

Comment: Although I voted to close, to be fair, how exactly do you search for `||=`  ?   The search box doesn't accept it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did do some googling first.

Answer (score 1):

in Ruby, we can write the following code to operate itself.

```
x += 1
```

this means equally

```
x = x + 1
```

In intialize process, we want set initial value to a variable only when it is nil or not exist.

For example,

```
a = a || initial_value
```

First, the left condition is evaluated.
If a is evaluated as false, the right condition is evaluated and a is assigned initial_value.

And, we can rewrite

```
a = a || initial_value
```

as the following

```
a ||= initial_value
```

Comment: It's actually `@current_user ||  @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]` if you read the Ruby source (meaning `||=` and `&&=` don't expand the same way as `+=` etc). See the link posted as a comment to the original question.

Comment: As Michael says, this is **wrong**. Please see [this answer for the correct expansion of `||=`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505285/211563).

Comment: Sorry about that. I did some googling first.