# If || has higher precedence than =, then why does `a || a = b` work?

Tags: ruby

I understand the difference between `||` and `or`, or `&&` and `and`, but what I don't understand is this:

Consider a method that returns the value of `@var`, or initializes it if `@var` is nil for false.

As I came from JavaScript background, I would write it like this, since `||` has higher precedence than `=`:

```
def some_method
  @var || (@var = MyClass.new)
end
```

or use `or`, since `or` has lower precedence:

```
def some_method
  @var or @var = MyClass.new
end
```

or more concisely:

```
def some_method
  @var ||= MyClass.new
end
```

But it so happened that this version **also works**:

```
def some_method
  @var || @var = MyClass.new
end
```

I search the web but didn't find useful results.

Most of them just tell the difference between `||` and `or`.

The operator precedence table clearly says that `||` has higher precedence than `=`.

I can even do `a = b || c = d` and Ruby sees it as `a = (b || (c = d))`.

Is this behavior documented somewhere or is it some kind of magic in Ruby?

P.S. CoffeeScript also has the same behavior.

**Update / Clarification**: This question is not about short-circuit evaluation. But about operator precedence. Please let me rephrase it again:

If `||` has higher precedence than `=`, then why does ruby sees `a || a = b` as `a || (a = b)`, but not `(a || a) = b` and raise a syntax error?

Comment: Don't know the answer but did made me think of an old LPC bug where you could write `!a = 1`. Perhaps you should try that as well.

Comment: Short-circuiting is the answer here.

Comment: @PerJohansson `!a = 1` works in Ruby. `a` becomes 1 and the expression evaluates to false, with a `warning: found = in conditional, should be ==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence becomes an issue only when there is ambiguity in the expression. In case of:

```
 @var || @var = MyClass.new
```

there is no ambiguity. The assignment operator `=` makes sense only if there is a single variable on the left side of it (disregarding the complexities that arise from multiple assignment). It does not make sense to assign something to a variable called "`@var || @var`". Therefore, there is no ambiguity. The only way to interpret the above expression is to interpret it as:

```
 @var || (@var = MyClass.new)
```

Therefore, precedence is not an issue here.

Comment: Or so one would guess. Could you back your words by pointers to rubyspec or MRI parser code?

Comment: +1, this answer makes most sense to me so far. I totally forget about the ambiguity, as most languages that I've used to (except Ruby) doesn't do anything like that. An example is JavaScript, which also has short-circuit evaluation. It just sees `a || a = 5` as `(a || a) = 5` and raises a SyntaxError. However I'm looking to see where it is documented, and trying to find the grammar that made this possible in Ruby.

Comment: Ok, I'd say this is an accepted answer. Looking at the (unofficial) grammars of Ruby, I saw that operators above the `=` operator lives in the same rule, which clearly made something like `a + a = 3` a valid grammar (and maybe some precedence may kick in later, although I couldn't find solid proof for this), unlike JavaScript which has top-down operator precedence, and thus make such an expression impossible.

Comment: `a || a = 5` doesn't read as `(a || a) = 5`. The precedence is irrelevant since `||` is left association while `=` is right. This parsing is a natural consequence of using a LALR parser.

Comment: @matyr Association matters only when the competing operators have the same precedence. Since `||` and `=` do not, association is irrelevant here.

Comment: Right, I brainfurted there. As answered `a || a` cannot be the left of `=`. The parser shifts more and resolves `a = 5` as the right of `||`.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby uses what is called `short-circuit evaluation` to evaluate logic expressions like these. The second argument will only be considered when the first is insufficient to evaluate the expression.

In your example, since `@var` is initially `nil`, the latter half of the expression is evaluated and set to an instance of `MyClass.new`.

The expansion of those expressions is pretty interesting. There are a few blog posts [here](http://procnew.com/ruby-short-circuit-edge-case-response.html) and [here](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2008/3/25/a-short-circuit-edge-case) that cover it quite nicely.

Comment: The links you gave covered just about how `a ||= b` expands to `(a || a = b)`, but not why `||` suddenly has lower precedence than `=` when it as at the left of `=`. But these links are an interesting read. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about `and` and `or` completely.  Just use `&&` and `||`, with parenthesis if you need them.

Your last example only works because you're using an instance variable.  Consider the difference here:

```
1.9.3> newvar
NameError: undefined local variable or method `newvar' for main:Object
        from (irb):59
        from /home/don/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3> @newvar
 => nil
```

If you try `newvar || newvar = 3` it will raise an error.

You might want to look at this SO question: [What does ||= (or-equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: Sorry, that did not answer my question. Try initializing `newvar` to nil and then `puts newvar || newvar = 42`. It has the same effect as `puts newvar = newvar || 42`. Please see the clarification I added to this question.

Comment: Okay, the answer to your question in the clarification is short-circuiting, like others have said.  I'm just saying, the only reason your last version worked was because you weren't using undefined variables.  `||=` does not behave the same way as `+=` and others, because it handles the case of undefined variables gracefully.