# Why does ||= on a hash reassign a false value?

Tags: ruby, hash

```
foo = { bar: false }
foo[:bar] ||= true
```

I expected that to function like `foo[:bar] = true unless foo.key? :bar` but it does not. Is there a shorter way to conditionally declare a hash value if it has not already been declared?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.fetch` if you don't need to store the value

```
hash.fetch(:key, :default)
```

Or give Hash a proc.

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = 'default-value' }
hash[:a] = 'foo'
p hash[:b]
# => 'default-value'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does ||= on a hash reassign a false value?

Because that's what it's there for: assign if false, otherwise leave alone. What else should it do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work has been discussed, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby#2505285).

Depending on your use case, setting a default value to the hash may be the most appropriate solution:

```
foo = {}
foo.default = true
```