# Ruby test and assign variable

Tags: ruby

Based on what I have read about the `||=` operator in Ruby, I would expect that the following line of code should assign the variable `a` (an as yet unassigned variable) in the example to `5`.

```
a |= "-----n-".index /n/
```

Just evaluating  `"-----n-".index /n/` on its own gives you `5`.

However, after executing the above line, `a` is set to `true`.

The following sets `b` to `false`, whereas I would expect that `b` should be `nil`:

```
b |= "-----n-".index /o/
```

Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: `|` is the *bitwise* `OR` operator while `||` is the *logical* `OR` operator. On the other hand, `||=` is not an operator. The parser will see `a ||= b` and treat it as `a = a || b`. You can just focus on `||` or `|`.

Comment: That's his error, yes. But why bitwise OR returns boolean when applied to undefined variable - that's a puzzle!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it is not undefined. The parser set to `nil` all ` var = anything` variables.

Comment: @oldergod: I know but the [question still stands](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15563200/125816).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It does if you consider a `nil` valued variable being undefined...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did get a bit mixed up with |= and ||=, but even with ||=, a still ends up wrong. So I am going to revise my answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the answers to it, so I reverted back to the original question :-/

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `a |= expr` is desugared to `a = a | expr`. In the right hand side, `a` is initially `nil`.

That expression is equivalent to `a = nil | expr`, which returns true if the argument is non-nil (see [documentation on **nil#|**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-7C) for details). You probably meant to write `a ||= expr` which is desugared to `a = a || expr`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and got mixed up between |= and ||=. Mmmm, I do see now that it works.

Comment: `a ||= expr` **IS NOT THE SAME** as `a = a || expr`. It is sometimes the same as `a || a = expr` but not always. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505285/421705

Answer (score 1):

`||=` and `|=` are different operators. You talk about one, but use another. Pay attention!

```
a ||= "-----n-".index(/n/) # => 5
b ||= "-----n-".index(/o/) # => nil

c |= "-----n-".index(/n/) # => true
d |= "-----n-".index(/o/) # => false
```