# Bitwise OR returns boolean when one of operands is nil

Tags: ruby

Why does bitwise OR return a boolean here. Of all the operators, I would least expect that from bitwise ones.

```
nil | 5 # => true
nil | 0 # => true
nil | true # => true
nil | false # => false
nil | nil # => false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15563154/125816) in the same topic :)

Turns out that [NilClass#|](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-7C) is overridden:

```
false | obj → true or false
nil | obj → true or false
Or—Returns false if obj is nil or false; true otherwise.
```