# Meaning of ||= symbol

Tags: ruby, symbols

I have a simple question about the meaning of a symbol (I think). What's the mean of ||= in ruby? I have a code snippet that say:

... `||= [nil]`

Is as "<<" ? ordinary method?

Comment: Please close for my duplicate finding and not the other one; the duplicate I linked to provides much more depth and focus about the specific operation in answers.

Comment: See also [What does `||=` mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x ||= y
```

means (almost) the same thing as

```
x = x || y
```

(it only evaluates `x` once, though.)

It is used mostly for checking if a variable is falsy (`nil` or `false`), and if so, setting it to a default value.

Comment: It is not strictly equivalent in Ruby (although it is in JavaScript). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505285/2246674 which explains the better approximation.

Comment: It actually behaves like `x || x = y`, though most of the times that won't make any difference. See http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html