# or equal vs equal

Tags: ruby

I'm looking over someone's codes and wondering about the difference between:

```
def blah
  @hello ||= [1,2,3].collect{|x| x+1}
end
```

and

```
def blah 
  @hello = [1,2,3].collect{|x| x+1}
end
```

I understand that `||=` means "or equal", but why do we need it? An example would be great.

Also, for the `collect` method, let's say I have an array:

```
a = [1,2,4,5]
```

and I wanted to find the array that contains integers that are greater than `2`, how can I use `collect` with that?

```
a.collect{|x| x>2} # => [false, false, true, true]
```

I want `[4,5]`.

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||=` does nothing if the variable has been assigned a value (other than `false` or `nil`):

```
irb(main):001:0> blah ||= 'foo'
=> "foo"
irb(main):002:0> blah ||= 'bar'
=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> puts blah
foo
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> blah = nil
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> blah ||= 'bar'
=> "bar"
irb(main):006:0> puts blah
bar
=> nil
```

One possible use is to assign variables in a fault-tolerant way. Compare:

```
@data = get_data_from_some_source
@data ||= get_data_from_fallback_source
@data ||= get_data_from_last_resort_source
```

with:

```
@data = get_data_from_some_souce
if @data == nil
  @data = get_data_from_fallback_source
end
if @data == nil
  @data = get_data_from_last_resort_source
end
```

or even (saints preserve us):

```
begin
  @data = get_data_from_some_source
rescue GettingDataDidntWorkException
  begin
    @data = get_data_from_fallback_source
  rescue GettingDataDidntWorkException
    @data = get_data_from_last_resort_source
  end
end
```

Haskell programmers will recognize this as similar in use to the `Maybe` monad.

Answer (score 1):

> a = [1,2,4,5] and I wanted to find the array that contains integers that are greater than 2,

Here we go using [`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
 a.select{|e| e > 2 } # => [4,5]
```

Explanation of the part `@hello ||= [1,2,3].collect{|x| x+1}` can be found [What does ||= (or equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: This is the write way.

Answer (score 0):

The page [What does ||= (or-equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby) does not mention the "proxy design pattern", which it is in a nutshell.

The first time you call that line, the .select stuff gets evaluated. The second time, the system re-uses the `@hello` value, without re-assigning it. Due to "boolean short-circuiting", things to the right of a `||` don't evaluate, if the left side is not `false` or `nil`.

(Also, if you never evaluated `@hello` before, Ruby automagically creates one, and assigns `nil` to it. So Ruby lets you proxy in one line, as an optimization.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so ||= means if you already have a previous value for your variable it will keep it
else, if it doesn't have any pre-assigned value, then it will take whatever value you set it equal to.

EX:

```
@hello = [1]

def blah
  @hello ||=[1,2,3]
end

blah 

@hello => [1], not [1,2,3]
```