# Rails fragment caching "expires_in" value is always recalculated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, fragment, cache-expiration

Does anyone know why rails seems to recalculate the value of "expires_in" each time a cached fragment is read?

#### EXAMPLE

```
cache("usecase_#{usecase.id}", :expires_in => "#{usecase.minutesToNextRun}".to_i.minutes) do
    some code
end
```

If I check the logs I see that the `usecase.minutesToNextRun` method is called each time the cache fragment is read (which is quite expensive and slows down the app).

#### THEORY

Normally I'd expect rails to just calculate the `:expires_in` value once and then just compare this value (e.g. 5 minutes) to the current time (in pseudocode).

```
if time_the_fragment_was_stored + expires_in > now
    do nothing
else
    re-render fragment
end
```

#### QUESTION

Does anyone have any hint/idea how I can prevent rails from recalculating the expiry time each time the fragment is read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before this part of code (or in your controller or presenter):

```
cache("usecase_#{usecase.id}", :expires_in => "#{usecase.minutesToNextRun}".to_i.minutes) do
  some code
end
```

try this:

```
@minutes_to_next_run ||= usecase.minutesToNextRun
```

in the example above, if `@minutes_to_next_run` is `nil`, then it is set equal to `usecase.minutesToNextRun`.  If it has a value, it uses it.  If you read it symantically, it makes sense:

> @minutes_to_next_run OR @minutes_to_next_run = usecase.minutesToNextRun

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby) is a (very) definitive answer about this

Comment: Hi, ... thanks for your fast answer...and it works :-)!!! could you tell me what the code actually changes? It just seems to call the function anyway (cause @minutes_to_next_run is not set)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the comment and link. Still the statement seems to say "if @minutes_to_next_run is not set (which it is not) assign usecase.minutesToNextRun" --> this should then still call usecase.minutesToNextRun which is the expensive call I wanted to circumvent :-)

Comment: right, the difference is that the expensive call only gets called once