# What is the "||=" construct in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my readings about structuring methods with options hashes for ruby, I've run into a coding "motif" a few times that I can't explain. Since I don't know what it's called, I'm having a lot of difficulty looking it up to learn more about it.

Here's an example:

```
1  def example_method(input1, options={})
2 
3     default_options = {
4         :otherwise => "blue",
5         :be_nil => nil
6       }
7 
8     options[:be_nil] ||= options[:otherwise]
9 
10    # other code goes down here
11  end
```

So above, on line 8, you can see what I'm talking about. From what I can put together, the line of code acts similarly to a tertiary operator. Under one condition, it sets a variable to one value... under a different condition, it sets the variable to a different value. In this case, however, the code updates a hash that's stored in the "options" variable. **Is that a correct assumption? Furthermore, what is this style/operator/functionality called?**

Comment: While I can't answer your question, the C-style operator you're referring to is a _[Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)_ - not _tertiary_ ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks @AdamS, I mess up terminology from time to time.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the duplicate! I was pulling hair trying to find similarities since google only searches alphanumerics!

Answer (score 0):

THis is a conditional assignment. The variable on the left will be assigned a value if it is nil or false. This is the short for of saying:

```
unless options[:be_nil]
  options[:be_nil] = options[:otherwise]
end
```

Comment: not just `nil` but any falsy value.