# What are hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This code is in my book, there are 2 lines that I don't understand.

```
# library.rb

class Library
   def initialize
       @books ={}  #creating a new hash
   end
   def addBook(book) 
       @books[book.category]||=[]          #category is a symbol. I DONT UNDERSTAND THIS LINE
       @books[book.category] << book       #AND THIS ONE
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by _category is a symbol_ ? It is a public property of the `book` object passed as a parameter to `addBook`.

Comment: Note there's a syntax error in the line where you append `book` to the array in `book.category`'s hash entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@books ={}
```

Above line will create a new Hash

```
@books[book.category]||=[]
```

This means `@books` is a `Hash` and `book.category` is it's `key` and if that key not exist assign an empty `array`

`||=` -> So this means `or-equals`

`||` means if `@books` has value it will not assign empty array, else it will put an empty `array`

So if `@books[book.category]` is a `Array`, in which you can insert as many `category` values

In this line we will insert `book` value into the hash, where `book.category` is the `key`

```
   @books[book.category] << book
```

If you try this

```
@books ={}
@books[book.category].push(book) # This will give you the error `undefined method 'push' for nilclass`
```

because

```
@books[book.category].class will return NilClass
```

Comment: Great answer, but what exactly this: ||=    means?

Comment: @TheKilz "or-equals", e.g., if there's nothing in that hash entry yet, put the empty array into it.

Comment: @TheKilz, x ||= [] is a shorthand of x = x || []

Comment: `a ||= b` It means "if a is false, nil or undefined, then evaluate b and set a to the result"

Comment: It's also called the "lazy initializer", that is it's often used to initialize something only if it hasn't been done before. In other words "`x` or assign *this* to `x` if that hasn't happened yet".

Comment: @TienNguyen I think x ||= [] is equal to x || x = []

Comment: @DinhNgocHien, it's syntax sugar like +=, -=, ... that is common in many languages

Comment: @DinhNgocHien Strictly speaking, it's actually neither. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27628662/1157054

Comment: @TienNguyen `x ||= []` being a shorthand of `x = x || []` is a misconception: http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: @Ajedi32 yes, it is indeed my mistake. *confused*

Answer (score 0):

`a ||= b` means "if a is `logically false` (`nil`, `false`, `undefined`), assign b to it". You can read more about `||=`, called "double pipe or equals" [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html).

So, in your code, `@books[book.category] ||= []` means that an empty array (`[]`) will be assigned to `books[book.category]` if it's `nil` - otherwise it will remain intact.

Then, in the line below (`@books[book.category] << book`), `book` is appended (`<<`) to the array. **Notice, however, that you have a syntax error (you open a `{` and you close with a `[`).**