# Ruby ||= operator acting funny

Tags: ruby, operators

From what I understand, `a ||= 7` means the following:
if `a` has a value, continue using that value, but if it does NOT have one, then set it to 7.

Here is what happens though.

If i have `a` and `b` as:

```
a = true

b = false
```

then

`a ||= b` ***=> true***

(in my interpretation: since 'a' DOES have a value, it remains that, and does not get equated to 'false' - so far so good.)

---

However, if i have them switched up like:

```
a = false

b = true
```

then `a ||= b` ***=> true***

so in this case my logic does not work, since it should return false, as "since 'a' has a value, it should not be assigned the value of 'b'", which apparently happens here.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Good discussion of `||=` (and `&&=`) [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html). Also, note that because `a ||= b` will override any falsy value (like `nil` and `false`), you don't want to use it on variables that can have legitimate values of `false` or `nil`.

Comment: Here is more detail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a ||= b
```

is equivalent to

```
a || a = b
```

this means `b` value is assigned to `a` if `a` is *falsy*, i.e. `false` or `nil`.