# Is there a Ruby shorthand for assigning a value from an array only if it is not nil?

Tags: ruby, operators

I have the following code:

```
via = reminders_array[i]['value']['bot-input-keyword'] unless reminders_array[i]['value']['via'].nil?
```

and

```
collection = json_element['COLLECTION']['$'] unless json_element['COLLECTION'].nil?
```

When I search for examples, I saw people use `||=` but I can't quite understand its use, especially in the second case.

Comment: [Concerning `||=`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: `collection = json_element['COLLECTION']['$'] unless json_element['COLLECTION'].nil?` this could also be written as `collection = json_element['COLLECTION']['$'] if json_element['COLLECTION']` but I would need more context to truly understand the problem here

Answer (score 1):

Consider the the following statements:

```
e #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `e'...

if false
  e = 7
end
e #=> nil 

f #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `f'
f = 7 if false
f #=> nil
```

As you see, Ruby raises an exception if the value of a local variable (`e` or `f`) is sought, but if the variable first appears in a statement, but is not assigned a value, Ruby sets its value to `nil`. We see that:

```
a = b unless c.nil?
```

is the same as:

```
a = b if c
```

which is the same as:

```
a = (c ? b : nil)
```

which is the same as:

```
a = c && b
```

To see why the last expression is equivalent to the preceding two, let's try a couple of examples, both with:

```
b = 4

c = 2
c && b #=> (2 && 4) => 4

c = nil
c && b #=> (nil && 4) => nil
```

So I believe you want:

```
via = reminders_array[i]['value']['via'] &&
  reminders_array[i]['value']['bot-input-keyword']
```

You asked about `||=`, which is a form of [abbreviated assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment). When Ruby's sees `a ||= b` she makes the assignment `a = b` if `a` is `nil` or `false`:

```
a || a = b
```

Two more examples, with `b` still equal to `4`:

```
a = 2
a ||= 4 #=> a || a = 4 => a => 2 || a = 4) => 2

a = nil
a ||= 4 #=> a || a = 4 => a => nil || a = 4 #=> 4
```

So if `a` is `nil`, `a` remains `nil`; else `a` is set to `b`.

A common use of `||=` is:

```
a = nil
(a ||= []) << 4
  #=> [4]

a = [4]
(a ||= []) << 6
  #=> [4,6]
```

In the first instance, `a` is `nil`, so `a ||= []` converts `a` to an empty array, to which it appends `4`. In the second case, `a` (`[4]`) is not `nil`, so `a ||= []` leaves `a` unchanged (`[4]`). `6` is then appended to `a`, making `a` `[4,6]`.

In addition to `||=` there are:

```
a &&= b #=> a && a = b
a += b  #=> a = a + b
a *= b  #=> a = a * b
```

and others (see the doc). A word about `a && b`. If `a` is `nil`, `a && b` is `nil`. If `a` is not `nil`, `a && b` is `b`. Notice that for operators `op` other than `||` and `&&`, `a op= b` is expanded to `a = a op b`.