# Clean object oriented code

Tags: ruby, oop, coding-style

I'm trying to be a better developer and I always ask myself If there is a better way to do the things. Is not the first time that I have to deal with this problem so I decided to ask what you think about it.

Let's say I have to implement a class that represent a product.

```
class Product 
  def initialize (name, net_price)
    @name = name 
    @net_price = net_price
    @gross_price = nil
  end

  def set_gross_price
    @gross_price = heavy_gross_price_calculation
  end

  def export
    @gross_price.nil? && set_gross_price
    return product.to_hash
  end

  def heavy_gross_price_calculation
    #  This function calculate the gross price but let's say that this is 
    #  pretty onerous operation that involves maybe also an external API
    #  request
  end
end
```

Let's say that the work flow for this class is create a product, calculate the gross price and export it for future use. 
Is it correct to not call the `set_gross_price` method in the `initialize`?
The fact is that when you export a product the gross price have to be calculated but I don't think that the correct choise is to force the developer to call `set_gross_price` before `export` but also i'm not sure about the first line of the `export` method beacause the set should concern about set the gross price and not check if it is null. 
Do you have some better way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm this question is possibly a better fit for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I think you are mixing two concerns (an object holding the data of a product and how you calculate the price)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail @pascalbetz

Answer (score 0):

I see several approaches:

- Make `Product` a stupid object which just holds the information about a Product, calculate the price externally
- Make `gross_price` a method which *memoizes* the result of the calculation

**Stupid Object**

```
class Product
  def initialize(name, net_price, gross_price)
    @name ...
    ...
  end
end

class GrossPriceCalculator
  def initialize()

  end

  def call(net_price)
    # complicate operation goes here
    # ...
  end
end
```

**Memoization**

```
class Product
  def initialize(name, net_price)
    @name = name
    @net_price = net_price
  end

  def gross_price
    @gross_price ||= calculate_gross_price
  end

  private

  def calculate_gross_price
    # here is the complicate operation..
    #
  end
end
```

I prefer first solution. It does not trigger a potentially expensive call hidden by some completely different operation (like export)

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree that if the heavy computation is only needed for the export, then you shouldn't do it in the initialize (as a concrete case, think of writing unit tests; why should all the tests pay the price of a heavy computation when it is needed for a single method?).

One way to avoid things like `@gross_price.nil? && set_gross_price` is to do a one-time assignment if the variable is empty by using `||=` (see e.g. [What does ||= (or-equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby)). At the same time, by using attribute accessors you can abstract yourself form when that computation is performed, and lazy compute that on the getter:

```
class Product

  attr_reader :name, :net_price

  def initialize (name, net_price)
    @name = name
    @net_price = net_price
    @gross_price = nil
  end

  def gross_price
    @gross_price ||= heavy_gross_price_calculation
  end

  def export
    return to_hash
  end

  def heavy_gross_price_calculation
    puts "heavy calculation"
    1000
  end

  def to_hash
    Hash[instance_variables.map do |var_name|
      # Remove the "@"
      name = var_name.to_s[1..-1]
      [name, send(name)]
    end]
  end

end
```

I'm giving here a possible `to_hash` implementation, but of course you can use a different one, as long as it uses the accessors and not the inst vars directly.

Then in a console you can do (see that "heavy calculation" is printed only once, the first time `export` is called):

```
2.2.3 :001 > p = Product.new('X', 100)
 => #<Product:0x0000000104e128 @name="X", @net_price=100, @gross_price=nil> 
2.2.3 :002 > p.export
heavy calculation
 => {"name"=>"X", "net_price"=>100, "gross_price"=>1000} 
2.2.3 :003 > p.export
 => {"name"=>"X", "net_price"=>100, "gross_price"=>1000} 
2.2.3 :004 >
```

One advantage of this is that any other method besides `export` that needs `gross_price` can also get it, with all the benefits `export` already has and the computation only needs to be done once.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to be a better developer ...

You're on the right track.

You have detected the scent of SRP. Your `Product` is doing at least 2 things:

1. Being a product with name and price
2. Exporting
3. Calculating gross prices

I think if you create 1 or 2 more classes the smell will go away.

You may want to read [POODR](http://www.poodr.com/). And write specs.