# What does it even mean to put a block after an assignment?

Tags: ruby, syntax

The following code snippet fully describes the problem, but I have to type all these extra words in to get SO to let me post it.

```
some_var ||= some_other_var do
   # Does this run every time, or only sometimes?
   stuff
end
```

Comment: Did it occur to you to use the length requirement to ask a question?

Comment: @JoshLee The question is right there in the title. Did you not see it?

Comment: There's nothing *to* search. Google does not accept `||=` as a search term.

Comment: Titles aren't questions, instead they introduce the subject. Your question is poorly asked and shows very little effort. "[ask]" and the linked pages would be good reading.

Comment: Google does if you put it in quotes. https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+ruby+%2B+%22%7C%7C=%22+block

Comment: The search returns nothing relevant, so apparently nobody has documented this usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such code will be evaluated just like any other with a `||=` operator. If `some_var` is `nil` or `false` the function will run and return value will be assigned to `some_var`; otherwise the value of `some_var` will be returned. See [What does ||= (or-equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby) for reference.

Comment: But what about the block? I found some code that puts a block after the assignment (as shown in my example), which makes absolutely no sense and isn't documented in any place that I know of. AFAIK, it should be a syntax error. In fact, the question you linked to has no answers that discuss putting a block after the `||=` assignment.

Comment: The block is simply a "special type of argument" passed to a method (in your example the method is `some_other_var`); you don't pass a block to a variable. The method with a passed block will be evaluated and its return value will be assigned to `some_var`.

Comment: Damn Ruby and its confusing syntax! I failed to remember that `some_other_var` can actually be a method call. Thanks.