# Ruby default assignment ( ||= ) vs Rescuing error

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Since `a ||= 1` is equivalent to `a || a = 1`, one can state that this is synctactic sugar for this:

```
if a.nil?
  a = 1
end
```

Likewise, given that `session` is a hash-like object, the following:

```
def increment_session_counter
  session[:counter] ||= 0
  session[:counter] += 1
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
def increment_session_counter
  if session[:counter].nil?
    session[:counter] = 0
  end
  session[:counter] += 1
end
```

Does that mean that the implicit `if` statement will be executed every time in the original definition of `increment_session_counter`? Since `session[:counter]` will mostly likely be `nil` only the first time (i.e. << 1% of the time), I have the feeling that the following code is better, since the implicit `if` won't be fired every time:

```
def increment_session_counter
  session[:counter] += 1
rescue NoMethodError
  session[:counter] = 1
end
```

Is this code better in such sense?

Having said that, I have no idea how `Rescue` is implemented in ruby and whether it's actually relevant regarding the tiny little optimization that can bring if so.

Comment: Raising and rescuing an exception is a quite expensive operation whereas a check for `nil` is very simple and fast. Therefore I would say it is most of the time faster and a better practice to check for `nil`.

Comment: Above has answered your qery, but I thought I would point out that your first 'if' example is incorrect as at no point does it assign a value to 'a'

Comment: Yep.. Typo here.. Fixed.. *It was only `a` inside the if* (BTW, thank you for the edit Sawa)

Comment: About the expensiveness of exception handling, I had doubts about that but you confirmed me that the `||=` idiom for that assignment purpose is indeed the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I just tried to fire 1 million times this method using both versions... The result is interesting.. With the `||=` operator I got an average of 2300 ms. While with the rescue version I got an average of 1300 ms. This seems to be not a big deal since I ran 1 million times but this count is not so excessive regarding the amount of data we've used to play nowadays.. So I have an idea performance. I still wait for thoughts about the idiom itself. E.g. I know that the error that being rescued should be as focused as possible in order to avoid other errors to be _ignored_.

Comment: I ran some benchmarks on my machine and found out that raising an exception is about 200 times slower than checking for `nil` upfront. That said it depends on the rate of misses what version will be faster. If you expected the number of misses vs the number of successful increments to be lower than  ~ 1/200 then `rescue` might be faster. On higher rates, a check for `nil` might be better. On the other hand, given how little the difference is, I would still prefer the Ruby idiom `||=` over an exception, because of readability reasons.

Comment: It's a simple piece of code, not a complicated algo. Don't think (too much) about what's can be faster. **Measure it** and you will **know**.

Comment: @SanjiBukai If performance is that critical to you, and I think it probably isn't, then you should be prepared to put tests in place that will test the relative performance of *each* choice of algorithm that you make. This would let you verify that changes in platform or version have not modified the performance-optimal choice.

Comment: Yep.. In the meantime I did some more advanced tests.. I confirm the expensiveness of exception handling _when it occurs_ but in fact as you said the conclusion depends upon the expected number of unassigned value vs the successful numbers of existing value. Regarding the readability, yes there is no direct link between the missing variable and the `NoMethodError`. But if the error could be something like this `rescue ValueNotDefined` I think that this will be in turn more readable than `||=`.

Comment: @SanjiBukai Why do you have a `nil` or missing `:counter` value in the first place?

Comment: @Stefan I'm building something with trial and error.. So everything is not yet defined.. This counting is something that can be enabled or disabled.. But yes as also as Kathryn said, it could be easier to define everything upfront.

Comment: _"I'm building something"_ – don't waste your time on premature optimization, then.

Comment: In fact, it's more for learning purpose at this stage.. But indeed I spend enough time for that particular usecase ;-)

Comment: `a ||= 1` isn't equivalent to `a || a = 1`, e.g. when `a` is undefined. It's also surely not equivalent to your `if a.nil?` example. `a` could be undefined or `a` could be `false`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27628662/6419007)'s the best description I could find on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session[:counter] += 1` does three things:

1. fetch the value (`Hash#[]`)
2. increment the value (`Integer#+`)
3. store the incremented value (`Hash#[]=`)

That's pretty convenient, but its brevity also makes it inflexible.

Providing a default is much easier if you separate the steps:

```
def increment_session_counter
  session[:counter] = session.fetch(:counter, 0) + 1
end
```

Comment: I had missed that answer.. Even if the intent could be less clear at first glance, i like this syntax. In other less trivial circumstances it could be more useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Catching the error is a pretty clever idea, but it's also harder to read than using `||=`. But *even easier* would be to set the initial value when you create the hash in the first place:

```
@session = {:counter => 0}
def increment_session_counter
  @session[:counter] += 1
end
```

That doesn't work when the key isn't known beforehand:

```
def increment_user_counter(username)
  @session[username] ||= 0
  @session[username]  += 1
end
```

However, in that case your assumption that the value of the counter is only nil once is thrown into jeopardy. In fact, since [many distributions follow the power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Empirical_examples), it's likely 1 will be the most common count.

Therefore, if you know the possible values beforehand, it's best to set them to zero when the program or class is initialized and skip the need for the default value check. And if you don't know all possible values upfront, you will likely find the `||=` statement is needed as often as not. There are probably few scenarios where using an exception is the best solution assuming [checking for `nil` is substantially cheaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491821/ruby-default-assignment-vs-rescuing-error/44493182#comment75979649_44491821).

Comment: Yep in the meantime I did some more tests and I found the same results as **spickermann** found. Regarding a forced initialization, I confirm that this is the best way to deal, but in a language like Ruby (or others) where metaprogramming is a very common usage some situation could not be defined in advance. I mean my usecase is a textbook case not so relevant..

Answer (score 1):

I tried some benchmarks with the following code. *This is a rails app. Rails v.5.1.1 / Ruby v2.4.1*

Originally the purpose is just to count the number of visits in any `show` actions of some controllers like so:

```
include SessionCount
...
def show
  ...
  @counter = increment_session_counter
  ...
```

Then I could display the counter in the relevant views.

So I made a concern with the appropriate code with both version of the *default assignment* I wanted to test:

```
module SessionCount
  private

  #Counter version A
  def increment_session_counter_A
    session[:counter] ||= 0
    session[:counter] += 1
  end

  #Counter version B
  def increment_session_counter_B
    session[:counter] += 1
  rescue
    session[:counter] = 1
  end
end
```

In order to test both versions of *default assignment* I changed my controllers code as following:

```
include SessionCount
...
def show
  ...
  t0 = Time.now
  1000000.times do
    session[:counter] = 0; #initialization for normalization purpose
    increment_session_counter_A
  end
  t1 = Time.now
  puts "Elapsed time: #{((end_time - beginning_time)*1000).round} ms"
  @counter = increment_session_counter_A
  ...
```

*Remark: In that code the initialization is here in order to enforce the "happy path" (where the value is not nil). In real scenario this will occurs only the first time for a given user.*

Here are the results:
I get an average of 3100 ms with version A (`||=` operator).
I get an average of 2000 ms with version B (`rescue`).

But the interesting part begins now..

In the previous code the code is executed following the *"happy path"* where no exception occurs.. 
So I changed the initialization I made for normalization purpose as following in order to enforce the *"exception path"*:

```
1000000.times do
  session[:counter] = nil; #initialization for normalization purpose
  increment_session_counter_A
end
```

And here is the results:
I get an average of 3500 ms with version A (`||=` operator).
I get <strike>an average of</strike> around 60 000 ms with version B (`rescue`). *Yes I tried a couple of times only..*

So here I can conclude as **spickermann** said that *exception handling* is indeed quite expensive.

But I think that there are many cases where the *first time initialization* happen very rarely *(like a blog where there is no post at the very beginning)*..
In such situations there is no reason to test for `nil` every time and it could be interesting to use the exception handling.

Am I wrong?

*I don't want to nitpick about some ms.. Here I just want to know if this idiom makes sense as a design pattern. I see the difference of both of these versions like the difference between `while... end` and `do ... while` since the intent is not the same.*