# Rails—what does &= do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operators

*To help future searches, it could also be described as "and equals" or "ampersand equals".*

I found this line in the Rails source code:

```
attribute_names &= self.class.column_names
```

What is the function of `&=`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The so-called operator-assignments of the form `a &= b`, where `&` can be another binary operator, is (almost but not quite — the boolean operators are a [notable exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby) having some corner cases where they differ) equivalent to `a = a & b`.

Since operators in Ruby are methods that are called on the left operand, and can be overridden, a good way to know what they are is to look at the documentation for the class of the left operand (or one of their ancestors).

`attribute_names` you found, given the context, is likely [`ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#attribute_names`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attribute_names), which

> Returns an array of names for the attributes available on this object.

Then we can see [`Array#&`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Array.html#method-i-26), which performs

> `Set` Intersection — Returns a new array containing unique elements common to the two arrays. The order is preserved from the original array.
>
> It compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

In general case, it performs `&` on left-hand and right-hand sides of the assignment and then assigns the result to the left-hand side.

```
11 & 10
# => 10
a = 11
a &= 10
a
=> 10

a = true
a &= false
a
#=> false
```

In your case it performs array intersection (`&` operator) and then assigns the result to the `attribute names`:

```
[1,2,3] & [2,3,4]
# => [2, 3]
a &= [2,3,4]
a
#=> [2, 3]
```