# handle missing local variable in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, local-variables

I have a `form` which is shared among some controllers. Sometimes I pass in `isbn` argument, sometimes not.

```
= form_for book do |f|
    - if isbn.present?
      = f.hidden_field :virtual_isbn_id, :value => isbn.id
```

How do I check if isbn is populated or not? Alternatively, how can I set isbn to be nil by default?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if defined? isbn ...`. You should take a look at this Question for example usage: [Checking if a variable is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-ruby)

Alternatively you can use `isbn.blank?` or `isbn.nil?` to check if the value is nil or blank (e.g. an empty string) if you know that the variable is present.

Answer (score 2):

Try `defined? isbn` to check if the variable exists.

```
- if defined? isbn and isbn
  = "isbn exists and is not nil"
```