# Ruby - how can I deal with a variable if it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby

I want do `puts blob`

but if the blob variable doesn't exist, I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `blob' for main:Object
```

I've tried

```
blob?  
blob.is_a?('String')
puts "g" if blob  
puts "g" catch NameError
puts "g" catch 'NameError'
```

but none work.

I can get around it by using an @instance variable but that feels like cheating as I should know about and deal with the issue of no value accordingly.

Comment: What sort of nasty magic are you doing where you aren't sure if a variable exists?

Comment: I program in rails and I want to make sure my methods can deal with variables not existing in a defensive programming pattern

Comment: Please explain a logical scenario where that could occur.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, you should do:

```
puts blob if defined?(blob)
```

Or, if you want to check for nil too:

```
puts blob if defined?(blob) && blob
```

The `defined?` method returns a string representing the type of the argument if it is defined, or `nil` otherwise. For example:

```
defined?(a)
=> nil
a = "some text"
=> "some text"
defined?(a)
=> "local-variable"
```

The typical way of using it is with conditional expressions:

```
puts "something" if defined?(some_var)
```

More about `defined?` on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288726/512507).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Object
  def try(*args, &block)
    if args.empty? and block_given?
      begin
        instance_eval &block
      rescue NameError => e
        puts e.message + ' ' + e.backtrace.first
      end
    elsif respond_to?(args.first)
      send(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end

blob = "this is blob"
try { puts blob }
#=> "this is blob"
try { puts something_else } # prints the service message, doesn't raise an error
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `something_else' for main:Object
```

Comment: Very similar to `Object#try` in `ActiveSupport`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: Yes but I think my version is more convinient.

Comment: Maybe, but the name suggests it's a lot more generic than it actually is by only catching the `NameError`. Things like `try {1/0}` will still fail, so IMHO it's too much for OPs request and too little for a generic solution.

Comment: Please, tell me more about generic solution becasue I'm going to build gem for try (it'll be tryit). I don't know how to start chat.

Comment: Well, catch more errors than just `NameError`. Also you probably want to be able to implement different error handling strategies, not just using `puts`.

Comment: Whatj might be an error handling strategies? Writing to log file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12812/discussion-between-megas-and-michael-kohl)