# echo if variable is defined in ruby/erb

Tags: ruby, erb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a variable is defined in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-ruby)

using Tilt's template `render` method, I pass in

```
#... t setup ...
t.render(self, { :a => 'test', :b => 'again' })
```

in my `template.erb`

```
<%= a %>
<%= b %>
```

say I remove `:b` from the hash that I pass to the template. The render will fail because `:b` is undefined.

in PHP, I could go:

```
<?= isset($foo) ? $foo : '' ?>
```

is there any clean way (in ruby/erb) to "echo if"?

I tried `<%= b.nil? ? b : '' %>` but that is obviously wrong.. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-ruby

Comment: helpful, but I guess my question is specific to erb template conventions

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`defined?` is the ruby equivalent to `isset()`.

```
<%= defined?(a) ? a : 'some default' %>
```

Comment: I believe this needs the `<%=` at the start; missing the equals at the start to echo.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to display nothing if `a` is not defined :

```
<%= a if defined?(a) %>
```

Also what you can do is set some default to `a` at the beginning of your partial if it's not defined. This way, you're assured that `a` won't crash on you and you don't have to test if it's defined everywhere. I prefer this way personally.

CAUTION : if you set `a` to `false` when you pass it to the template, it'll be reassigned to `""` in my example .

```
<% a ||= "" %>
#Then do some things with it. No crash!
<%= a %>
<%= a*10 %>
<%= "Here's the variable a value: #{a}" %>
```

Comment: `<%= a if defined? a %>` is great! thank you!

Comment: `nil?` wouldn't be safe, correct?

Comment: you can't test `a.nil?` if it's not defined, it'll crash. Use `defined?` to do it. You can however assign `nil` to `a` in my second example above as long as you just try to output it. If you want to call methods on it though, it'll crash ... !

Comment: Also I recommend using `irb` a lot to experiment and see what you can and cannot do with the language. It's a powerful tool every rubyist uses, even the experienced ones!