# Why does `defined?` keyword not return boolean?

Tags: ruby, conventions, defined

In ruby, most methods or keywords that end with `?` return boolean values. And we except them to behave like this. Why does `defined?` keyword return somethings else? Or why is there `?` at the end of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can be understood in two ways:

1. Why doesn't it simply return `true` or `false`?

It's because it encodes more information than simply if something is defined or not:

```
defined? Class # => "constant"
defined? 42    # => "expression"
defined? nil   # => "nil"
defined? x     # => nil
```

2. Why does it have `?` at the end since as the convention goes, the question mark is reserved for predicates?

You are right that this is inconsistent. The most likely reasons are:

- Almost always, you will use it as predicate anyway

  ```
  if defined? x
    # do something
  end
  ```
- The shortest alternative, which doesn't sound like a predicate I can think of is `definition_type_of`. Generally, you want to keep the reserved words in your language short

Comment: For me, the really wtf part around `defined?` has always been *why does it return strings and not symbols?*. I have absolutely no good answer for that...

Answer (score 2):

Developers chose to return something more meaningfull than `true` or `false` because the only case that breaks by not having boolean returned is explicit comparison:

```
defined?(:x) == true
# => always `false`
```

Such comparison is something you should usually not do, as logical operators like `||` and `&&` are just as likely to return some truthy object instead of `true`. This is barely needed for anything.

Answer (score -1):

The "defined?"-method can return more than "true" or "false". It tells you what type of variable it is if it's defined at all.

Check
[Checking if a variable is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined)
and 
http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F

Comment: That is not an answer. The question is why that is the case.