# Return if a variable is undefined

Tags: ruby

How do I create a condition inside a function that tests if a variable passed to a function is defined, and if it isn't, execute a command, otherwise execute the function?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
def your_method(parameter)
  if parameter
    # do something
  else
    puts "parameter has no value"
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this and got-> name error: undefined local variable, ...not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: @SlySherZ `0` is truthy in Ruby.

Comment: If the `parameter` could be a falsy value, like false, you'll need a more complex condition. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def foo bar
  return puts "..." unless defined?(bar) == "local-variable"
  # Otherwise, continue with the method
  ...
end
```

However, the variable `bar` assigned to the given argument is always defined. The `unless ...` condition will never be satisfied. So your question does not make practical sense.

Answer (score 0):

(If you're using Rails) Use `#try`, see: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dd7d5b7c800b4f6d32747913fc7c8d00ce94f03a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L54

```
def my_function(var)

  return "string here" unless try(var)

  # --or--
  #
  # execute_whatevs unless @object.try(var)
  #
  # execute_whatevs(var) unless try(var) 
  #
  # execute_something unless try(var)
  #
  # var.try(:execute_whatevs)
end
```